# Нужно помочь составить регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Требуется из этого html-кода:

```
<form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent" action="/accounts/login/">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="483301b520eb5eabeb4b35e4b5da743a"/>
    <ul class="errorlist"><li>Обязательное поле.</li></ul>
    <p><label for="id_username">Имя пользователя:</label> <input name="username" maxlength="30" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" type="text" id="id_username" /></p>
    <ul class="errorlist"><li>Обязательное поле.</li></ul>
    <p><label for="id_password">Пароль:</label> <input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>
    <p class="form-actions">
        <a href="/accounts/password/reset/">Забыли пароль?</a>
        <input type="submit" class="button-green" value="Войти" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Регулярными выражениями получить значение value, т.е. `483301b520eb5eabeb4b35e4b5da743a`. Может кто-то помочь составив регулярное выражение?

Comment: Судя по всему, вы пытаетесь регулярками распарсить HTML. Не надо так делать.

Comment: Смотрите [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105), тут написано, как правильно.

Comment: почему не надо так делать? мне нужно получить это значение для авторизации на сайте

Comment: @incorpus: Эх. Поищите по сайту html + regex. Это проговаривалось уже много раз. Для начала: как вы собираетесь определять, ваш код внутри комментария или нет?

Comment: @incorpus: Ещё несколько потенциальных проблем перечислены [там же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему в значении `input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]` могут находиться md5-хеши.

```
    string pattern = @"([0-9a-f]{32})";
    Regex regex = new Regex( pattern );
    Match match = regex.Match( str ); // str содержит html код из вопроса

    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: А через 5 минут после сдачи проекта, программисты сайта решают добавить в код вывод ещё какого-то хеша , совсем не связанного с первым.. Как назло, он попадает под условия регулярки.. И тут разработчика начинают дико материть, хоть он и вроде бы "не виноват" и "всё работало же" XD

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Дык поэтому регексы и не советуют юзать. Но вопрос звучал как "помочь составить регулярное выражение", вот и помог.

Comment: Понятно. ) Ну я просто как дополнение написал - что бы было понятно к чему могут привести регулярки )

Answer (score 3):

Используйте CSS-селекторы, либо XPath вместо регулярных выражений.

1. Это сильно упростит составление условий для выборки нужных элементов из HTML-кода.
2. Это сократит вероятность того, что ваш парсер сломается как только дизайнер/програмист оригинального сайта решать банально что-то поменять местами в коде.

   Да и если изменения будут крупными, то исправлять селекторы в разы проще, чем вспоминать как работала та или иная регулярка, и переписывать её заново.
3. (хоть и не этот случай сейчас, но..) - регулярные выражения порой совсем не применимы для HTML-кода.

Для выборок по CSS-селекторам на плаформе .NET вы можете использовать, [CsQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/) или [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp/).

Допустим, ваш html-код находится в переменной html:

```
string html =
    "<form method=\"POST\" id=\"login-form\" class=\"adjacent\" action=\"/accounts/login/\">" +
    "    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\" value=\"483301b520eb5eabeb4b35e4b5da743a\"/>" +
    "    <ul class=\"errorlist\"><li>Обязательное поле.</li></ul>" +
    "   <p><label for=\"id_username\">Имя пользователя:</label> <input name=\"username\" maxlength=\"30\" autocapitalize=\"off\" autocorrect=\"off\" type=\"text\" id=\"id_username\" /></p>" +
    "   <ul class=\"errorlist\"><li>Обязательное поле.</li></ul>" +
    "   <p><label for=\"id_password\">Пароль:</label> <input autocapitalize=\"off\" autocorrect=\"off\" type=\"password\" name=\"password\" id=\"id_password\" /></p>" +
    "    <p class=\"form-actions\">" +
    "        <a href=\"/accounts/password/reset/\">Забыли пароль?</a>" +
    "        <input type=\"submit\" class=\"button-green\" value=\"Войти\" />" +
    "    </p>" +
    "</form>";
```

Мы можем составить простой CSS-селектор для ваших условий(выбор элемента "input", у которого атрибут "name" равен "csrfmiddlewaretoken"):

```
string selector = "input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]";
```

Такое выражение довольно просто составить, и оно хорошо читается, не правда ли?

Дальше, используя его можно получить из html-кода необходимое значение(оно находится в атрибуте "value"):

**Пример с использованием CsQuery:**

```
var document = new CQ(html);
var value = document.Select(selector).Val();
```

**Пример с использованием AngleSharp:**

```
var document = new HtmlParser(html).Parse();
var value = document.QuerySelector("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").GetAttribute("value");
```

В итоге, в value мы имеем значение `483301b520eb5eabeb4b35e4b5da743a`, которое и хотели извлечь.