# Парсинг данных с сайта

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, парсер

Есть такая задача спарсить данные с продающего сайта объявлений. Проблема заключается в том, что там есть целый набор параметров поиска и фильтрации, и нужно парсить таким образом, чтобы двигать от большого к малому. К примеру, телефоны, далее марка телефона, далее год выпуска телефона, соответственно выборка сокращается. Все эти данные числа продукции, отзывов и оценок покупателей надо дергать с сайта. Потому второй вопрос к профессионалам, лучше сделать это через приложение или через сайт свой, который будет сливать данные с продающей информации? Есть какие-то наработки, советы, предложения по этому поводу? Буду признателен за информативные полезные ответы.

Comment: ссылку на сайт можете скинуть? или там закрытая регистрация?

Comment: Первый совет: прпробуйте договориться с сайтом о предоставлении информации. Второй совет: поймите, что синтаксический анализ тут в любом случае никаким боком... И третий: объясните (в первую очередь самому себе, ну и нам заодно): что подразумевается под " через приложение или через сайт"?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Rufanov, там надо много сайтов-объявлений анализировать. К примеру, авито.

Comment: @klopp, синтаксический анализ, это ставил не я), кто-то поправил мой вопрос, так что претензии не ко мне. Третий вопрос, то есть либо через веб-интерфейс реализовать такое, например, на php дергать данные с чужого сайта, либо на C#, delphi написать приложение, которое по заданной ссылке тоже будет дергать нужные значения. Вот и спрашиваю совета у работающих в этой сфере.

Comment: Я всё равно не понял, почему если на php, то это "сайт", а если на C#, то "приложение" :-) Ну да ладно, мелочи. Ищите HTML-парсер для своего языка и вперёд. Здесь их обсуждений - тонны.

Comment: @klopp, Вы что издеваетесь? На php если писать, на каком-то хостинге разворачивать свою логику, то соответственно это будет сайт. Если это на C# или делфи оконная программа, независимая от браузера, то это уже приложение. А вообще хватит ерундой страдать, лучше толковые советы дайте, чем придираться к каждому слову. Итак понятно же всем, что имел ввиду. Интересует приложение на delphi или же алгоритмы на php, которые парсят данные. Вопрос открыт по той причине, что я спрашиваю, как в условиях фильтрации (там списки разные) перебрать все товары, модели и так далее и составить анализ потом?

Comment: "*На php если писать, на каком-то хостинге разворачивать свою логику, то соответственно это будет сайт*" - что за бред? Перестаньте истерить и говорить ерунду, а поищите HTML-парсеры. Это и есть решение вашей задачи.  Если настолько сложно это сделать самостоятельно - наводка номер раз: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/ Других не будет, дальше без поводыря...

Comment: @klopp, я разве что-то не то сказал или истерил)? Разжевать вам просто, видимо, трудно, чем отличается сайт (веб-интерфейс) от приложения), потому слов уже не находится нужных). Просто я за конструктивный диалог, а не пустые иронии и придирки, если сказать особо нечего по вопросу, то лучше просто ничего не писать. За ссылку спасибо. Буду разбираться сам.

Comment: А это и есть по делу. Для решения вашей задачи вообще не нужны ни сайт, ни гуй. Причём независимо от того, на каком языке она будет решаться: плюсах, паскале, шарпе, пхп, перле или го. На всех из этих, и на многих других, достаточно одного: библиотеки для парсинга HTML. Но если у вас пока скриптовые языки ассоциируются только с сайтами, а нескриптовые - с оконными программами, то может быть непросто :)

Comment: @klopp, то есть по вашей логике php - это скриптовый язык)? Тогда вы сами путаете что-то). Можно и на шарпе в принципе поднимать сайт по технологии asp.net. Об этом я тоже в курсе, так что открытия Вы для меня не сделали). Не очень интересно просто общаться с людьми которые пытаются из себя что-то показать, унижая других). По библиотеке для парсинга HTML единой для всех языков хотел бы услышать подробнее, если можно).