# Поиск тегов без атрибутов в HTML с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: java, html, регулярные-выражения

Стоит задача поиска всех не повторяющихся тегов без атрибутов (например, `head`, `body`) в HTML файле с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String tmp = fileReader(fileName); //метод читает весь файл и возвращает строку, в которой мы ищем наши теги
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^> ]+>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tmp);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Данный код выводит все теги без атрибутов, а мне нужны только те, которые не повторяются.

Я пробовал так: `("<[^> ]+>")?`. `?` означает, что оно будет искать совпадения, которые повторяются 0 или 1 раз. Не работает.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Парсить HTML регулярными выражениями не надо. Никогда. Вот [обзор по .NET](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net).

Comment: Если задача _поставлена_ использовать регулярки — пора менять работу.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не сможете решить эту задачу чистыми регулярками в Java - в движке регулярок этого языка отсутствуют обратные позиционные проверки непостоянной длины, то бишь:

```
(?<![a-z].*)
```

Вы можете посмотреть как примерно могло бы выглядеть такое регулярное выражение:
https://regex101.com/r/iH6gR5/1

```
<(\w+)>(?=.*?(<\/\1>))(?!.*<\1)
```

Его проблема в том, что оно совпадает с последним DIV, так как справа от него нет другого DIV.

У меня нет .NET для тестирования регулярки (в нем есть `?<!.*`), но рабочий вариант должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
<(\w+)>(?<!<\1>.*<\1>)(?=.*?(<\/\1>))(?!.*<\1)
```

**P.S.** Регулярное выражение не учитывает комментарии, блоки CDATA и прочие прелести синтаксиса HTML, если добавить поддержку этого, то регулярка будет настолько сложной, что не принесет образовательного эффекта.

---

Не люблю так решать, когда ответ - смесь кода и регулярных выражений, поэтому сначала написал, что задача не решаема при помощи регулярных выражений.

```
String tmp = "<html><head></head><body><div></div><DIV><pre></pre></div></body></html>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "<([^> ]+)>(?=(?:.*<(\\1)>)?)", Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );
Matcher m = p.matcher(tmp);
List<String> exclude = new ArrayList<String>();
while ( m.find() ) {
    if ( m.group(2) != null ) {
        exclude.add( m.group(2).toLowerCase() );
    }
    if ( exclude.indexOf( m.group(1).toLowerCase() ) == -1 ) {
        System.out.println( m.group() );
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Были исключены `div`, так как они повторяются.

Comment: В шаблон «распарсить регулярками HTML невозможно» надо добавить «если вы не @ReinRaus» :)

Comment: @VladD это не так трудно, как кажется :-)

Comment: [Угу](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/276994) :-)

Comment: Получилось такое выражение - (<[^> /!-]+>)(?![\s\S]*\1) вроде работает и не учитывает коментрарии

Comment: Лучше `\w+`, про комментарии и цдата я начал речь, потому что внутри них могут быть тэги.

Comment: `[\s\S]` лишняя конструкция. Лучше использовать флаг ` S_DOT_ALL`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что Ваше выражение Вас устраивает? Оно же ловит последний из повторяющизся тэгов, то есть не удовлетворяет поставленному вопросу.