# Как спарсить ID людей из поисковика в вконтакте?

Tags: c#

добрый день. столкнулся со следующей проблемой, хочу спарсить ID людей при поиске в вконтакте, но, мне выдаётся не весь список людей, почему? Вот что делаю:

метод для отправки запроса

```
public string GLOBAL_SEARCH(string from, string to, string city, string country)
        {
            //string like = textBox4.Text.Substring(textBox4.Text.IndexOf("wall-", 0));

            cook = null; cook = new CookieDictionary();
            var request = new HttpRequest();
            request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
            request.Cookies = cook;
            request.AddParam("al", "1");
            request.AddParam("c[age_from]", from);
            request.AddParam("c[age_to]", to);
            request.AddParam("c[city]", city);

            request.AddParam("c[country]", country);
            request.AddParam("c[name]", "1");
            request.AddParam("c[photo]", "1");
            request.AddParam("c[section]", "people");
            request.AddParam("change", "1");

            HttpResponse response = request.Post("http://vk.com/al_search.php");
            return response.ToString();
        }
```

метод, распарсивающий полученный ответ:

```
string[] GLOBAL_SEARCH_GO()
        {
            string from = (string)numericUpDown1.Value.ToString();
            string to = (string)numericUpDown2.Value.ToString();
            string city = textBox5.Text;
            string country = textBox6.Text;

            List<string> f_list = new List<string>();
            var request = new HttpRequest();
            request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
            request.Cookies = cook;
            Regex newReg = new Regex("<div class=\"labeled name\"><a href=\"/(.*)\" onclick");

            while (true)
            {
                var z = GLOBAL_SEARCH(from, to, city, country);

                MatchCollection matches = newReg.Matches(z);

                if (matches.Count <= 0)
                    break;

                for (int i = matches.Count - 1, w = 1; i > -1; i--, w++)
                    f_list.Add(matches[i].Groups[1].ToString());
            }
            return f_list.ToArray();
        }
```

событие на кнопке:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox2.Items.AddRange(GLOBAL_SEARCH_GO());
            label11.Text = "Получено: " + listBox2.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
```

использую библиотеку xNet. Если что, для поиска авторизация не нужна

Comment: почему API не используете?

Comment: @Ni55aN , потому что хочу вот так попробовать сделать, программно)

Comment: А вот это и не нужно. Парсить то, что не предназначено для парсинга, неправильно. Есть официальное API, которое гарантирует правильный ответ, а вы пытаетесь вытащить данные из html. Да ещё [распарсить его регулярками](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105).

Comment: Это всё равно, что имея число, записать его в строку, римскими цифрами, закодировать, распечатать на бумаге, а потом отправить по факсу, сосканировать, распознать, расшифровать и выудить оттуда снова число.

Comment: @VladD никогда не любил апи) у вас нет примера для моего вопроса?

Comment: @inkorpus: Не-а. Я вообще никогда не пытался распарсить HTML вручную, это _очень_ сложная задача, если делать правильно. А делать неправильно неинтересно.

Comment: @VladD , я говорю об vk api. У тебя нет метода для моего случая?

Comment: @inkorpus: К сожалению, нет, никогда не программировал под vk.

Comment: вроде страница поиска с подгрузкой по мере скрола. поэтому всех и не показывает, поищите как пеерключать страницы вручную. но соглсне что нужно использовать VKApi

Comment: Можешь попробовать через селениум, а не через реквестЬІ. Тогда будет гарантировано правильнЬІй хтмл код которЬІйдовольно просто разобрать. Если нужно разбирать большое количество информации (например 2 минутки скролил вниз) советую для парсинга использова хтмлАгрилитиПак, т.к. селениум в чистом виде отвратительно работает с парсингом.

Answer (score 1):

К  POST  запросу  добавьте  параметр offset=0  . И так до 50. Запрос подробите по парметрам

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Оно базируется на показаниях  Снифера. ) Если вы отловите запросы при скролинге вы уведите ,что к POST  запросу добавляется параметр   offset . Начнайте с 0 и с шагом 20 до конца проходите.  И так можно спарсить  до 1000 Айди.  если  ваших результатов больше тысячи ,дробите запрос на подпросы.   Страна ,город,пол возраст и все  будет хорошо.

Comment: Мдя, как бы не извращаться - лишь бы не делать просто и надёжно :)