# Вывод текста в форму с сайта

Tags: c#, .net

Есть код.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://chitachok.ru/";
string text = client.DownloadString(url);
Regex regex = new Regex("footnote");
Match match = regex.Match(text);
label1.Text = text;
```

Он должен был выводить статистику сайта, а выводит весь код сайта.

Comment: Что делать, дайте пожалуйста совет !

Comment: А что за статистика? Вы в label1 присваиваете text скачанный со страницы

Comment: А мне нужно вывести только текст класса footnote. Вот статистика Всего: 330 (пользователей: 58, гостей: 174, роботов: 98)

Comment: Текст html элемента c классом footnote?

Comment: Да именно он...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var url = "http://chitachok.ru/";
var text = client.DownloadString(url);
var regex = new Regex(@"Всего: \d+ \(пользователей: \d+, гостей: \d+, роботов: \d+\)");
var match = regex.Match(text);
if (match.Success)
    label1.Text = match.Value;
```

и другой вариант регулярного выражения:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var url = "http://chitachok.ru/";
var text = client.DownloadString(url);
var regex = new Regex("<div class=\"footnote\">\\s*(.*)\\s*</div>", RegexOptions.Multiline);

var match = regex.Match(text);
if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 1)
    label1.Text = match.Groups[1].Value;
```