# Парсинг html с помощью html agility pack и linq

Tags: html, c#, linq, xmlparser, winrt

Есть часть html кода:

```
<span class="comments">
<a href="gtf">Нет комментариев</a>

 - Просмотров  60 

</span>
```

Как мне с помощью html agility pack и linq вытащить текст только между span не затрагивая текст в элементе a?

Пытался с помощью InnerText, но он вытаскивает и "нет комментариев" и " -просмотров 60".

Проект у меня для Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Для оформления кода в вопросе есть специальная кнопка в редакторе, выглядит как `{}`

Comment: Вы уже прочитали [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105)? Это раз.

Comment: А два — если у сайта есть официальное API, воспользуйтесь им. Если у сайта нету официального API, то он не хочет, чтобы с него парсили информацию, и вы не заслуживаете никакого сочувствия.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что чуть ли не у каждого второго сайта есть офф API? Если нету офф API для сайта это не означает что владелец таким образом не хочет что бы ктото писал клиент.

Comment: @АнтонЯстребов: Ну, если автор сайта согласен, чтобы для него писали клиент, ему не составит труда вынести данные в удобном виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим способом:

```
var spanElements = childElement.Descendants("span").Where(
                    x => x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains(("comments")));
foreach (var spanViewsElement in spanElements)
                    {
                        if (spanViewsElement != null){
collection.Add(spanViewsElement.LastChild.InnerText.Trim().Replace("-",""));}
```