# Как удалить спецсимволы из HTML строки?

Tags: c#, html

`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` почему-то превращает входную строку в вопросики (скорее всего, проблема в кодировке). `WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` не убирает символы `&gt`,`&lt` и т. д.

Есть ли универсальный способ очистить от этих "паразитов" строку?

Comment: Покажите код и пример строки, которая не проходит

Comment: скорее всего, проблема в кодировке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, и `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` совершенно корректно обрабатывают и любые символы, и HTTP escape-последовательности:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;b&gt;пони&lt;/b&gt;"));
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;b&gt;правят миром&lt;/b&gt;"));
```

Вывод:

```
<b>пони</b>
<b>правят миром</b>
```

С функциональной точки зрения эти методы эквивалентны, они [отличаются только сборками и версиями .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894322).

Если у вас "вопросики", то, вероятно, строка изначально в неверной кодировке. Убедитесь, что после получения строки её содержимо нормально отображается.

Если же вас интересуют именно последовательности `&gt`и `&lt`, то они некорректные, так как не оканчиваются точкой с запятой. При каких-то условиях некорректные последовательности могут всё равно обрабатываться парсерами HTML, будто они корректные. Чтобы получить подобное поведение, воспользуйтесь полноценными [парсерами HTML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net/420355#420355).

Строки с "паразитными lt и gt" и "вопросиками" обычно не появляются просто так. Скорее всего, вы выковыряли их из HTML файла каким-то топорным способом, например, регулярками, а потом пытаетесь получить нормальный текст. Настоятельно рекомендую пользоваться полноценными парсерами, потому что они не только решат ваши проблемы с "мусорными символами", то и значительно упростят извлечение информации из HTML файлов.

Comment: а как теги <b> тоже удалить?

Comment: @Radzhab654654 Пройдите по ссылке в ответе, там список парсеров HTML. CsQuery, HAP и AngleSharp умеют извлекать текст без тегов.