# Регулярное выражение для парсинга ссылок

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Как спарсить ссылку на сайт вот от сюда?

```
<li data-bm="6" class="b_algo"><h2><a href="http://php.net/manual/en/index.php" h="ID=SERP,5100.1"><strong>PHP</strong>: <strong>PHP Manual</strong> - Manual</a></h2></li>
```

Comment: Это зависит от того что вы понимаете под парсингом. Что вы хотите получить из ссылки

Comment: Мне из  html кода нужно вытягивать ссылки такого типа

Comment: Лучше отталкиваться от тегов в которых они находятся функциями DOM. И если регулярками, то все равно лучше от тегов отталкиваться. В кривых url запросто могут встретится какие нибудь кавычки и поди отличи ее после этого от кавычек в которые она заключена

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Лучше использовать CSS селекторы для такого дела. Есть библиотека AngleSharp офигенная, с нугета можно скачать

Comment: Мне нужно через Regex

Comment: Вот код парсинга http://prntscr.com/a1hgcz Как оттуда распарсить ссылку?

Comment: Вам сюда: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) для таких целей, но если вас устроит грубый Regex, то:

```
var result = Regex.Match(input,
                         @"<a [^>]+? href \s*=\s* ([""']) (?<url>[^\1]*?) (\1)",
                         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
if (result.Success)
{
    return result.Groups["url"].Value;
}
```