# C# Substring найти каждое вхождение подстроки

Tags: c#, строки

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как получать N-ое вхождение подстроки в строку. 
Допустим есть

```
<title>Заголовок 1</title>
<title>Заголовок 2</title>
<title>Заголовок 3</title>
```

Сначала нужно получить *Заголовок 1*, затем *Заголовок 2*, затем *Заголовок 3*
Видел нечто вроде

```
Header = Fulltext.Substring("<title>","</title>")[i]
```

Но у меня компилятор такое не воспринимает.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну у Вас же явный XML, парсите его и извлекайте нужный тег

Comment: еще, думаю, можно использовать string.split() для указания разделителей (теги в данном примере)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если входной текст у вас HTML/XML - то лучше воспользоваться соответствующими методами для их обработки. Посмотрите вопрос [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net), в нем перечислены основные методы для работы с HTML.

Например, можно выбрать заголовки через CsQuery ([nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/)):

```
using CsQuery;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication24
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Fulltext = @"<title>Заголовок 1</title>
<title>Заголовок 2</title>
<title>Заголовок 3</title>";

            var allTitles = CQ.Create(Fulltext).Select("title")
                .Select(el => el.LastChild.NodeValue)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Если же входной текст у вас не HTML, не XML, а просто текст в котором нужно найти строки определенного вида, то можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication24
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Fulltext = @"<title>Заголовок 1</title>
<title>Заголовок 2</title>
<title>Заголовок 3</title>";

            List<string> allTitles = Regex.Matches(Fulltext, @"\<title\>(?'title'.*)\</title\>")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups["title"].Value)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```