# Как найти документацию по AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, github, парсер

Мне понадобилось распарсить таблицу на [этой странице](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_globex_options.html?optionExpiration=J6) из кода на C#.
Google подсказал мне откуда начать:

[Распарсить HTML в .NET и выжить: анализ и сравнение библиотек](https://habrahabr.ru/post/273807/)

[Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net)

Мой вывод: AngleSharp, так как:

1. Поддерживается и развивается
2. "...Количество различных плюшек, облегчающих работу просто поражает воображение, к примеру **IHtmlTableElement**..."

Ожидаю что выбранная библиотека поможет решить 2 задачи:

1. извлечь и DOM страницы HTML-код таблицы;
2. "облегчающим работу способом" в 1-2 команды преобразовать HTML в таблицу - некую форму, к которой из C# можно обращаться по строкам и столбцам.

Ищу как решить первую задачу. [На главной странице проекта в GitHub](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) в Simple demo сразу нахожу строку `document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);` Этот метод выбирает все заданные элементы, а у меня только один. Разгадка близко. Следует изучить методы того класса, экземпляром которого является `document` и, среди них, ну точно будет искомый. А имя класса мне подскажет VisualStudio.

С главной страницы - очень удобно - сразу перехожу по ссылке [Documentation](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation). 
**Requirements**, **Getting AngleSharp over NuGet**, **First steps**, **The DOM** (отличная иллюстрация в тексте), **Beyond the DOM** (ага, снова `var elements = document.QuerySelectorAll("li").Attr("test", "test");`. Хороший текст, завершается жизнеутверждающим *to be continued*.

Хорошо, далее иду в [Wiki](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki). Вот они - все ответы! **Documentation**, **API**, **Interfaces**, **Examples** и ещё много ссылок но мне уже некогда. Да и не хочется. Хочется распарсить табличку.

Проверяю  [Documentation](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation). Ну да, здесь уже был.
**API** - открывается главная.
**Interfaces** - открывается главная.
**Examples**  - открывается главная.

Пол-часа беспорядочных поисков. Ага, вот же в **Documentation** справа "**Pages**" - и с него ссылки ведут куда обещано.

Ещё раз по списку. 
[API](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Api) - просто текст, не вчитываюсь.
[Interfaces](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Interfaces) - просто текст, не вчитываюсь.
[Examples](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Examples) -  есть код. 7 примеров. Документации нет. Ищу поиском "Query". Нахожу старого знакомого `QuerySelectorAll` и yahoo!  `var emphasize = document.QuerySelector("em");` Однако, закрадываются сомнения - **Query** это запрос, а запрос это что-то вроде `List<IEnumerable>`, а мне нужен 1 элемент с уникальным ID.

Очень хочу доки, в идеале - как на MSDN. Ну или примеры кода - мне всего-то несколько строк нужно приспособить. Без претензий к использованию памяти и производительности.

[Ok, Google: "anglesharp samples"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=anglesharp%20samples&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), находится новая ссылка [AngleSharp.Samples](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples). Отличные картинки! На на картинках есть ссылка: http://anglesharp.github.io - тоже не то. Ладно, сверху дерево папок и файлы. [AngleSharp.Samples.App](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples/tree/master/AngleSharp.Samples.App) не то,  [AngleSharp.Samples.Demos/Snippets/](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples/tree/master/AngleSharp.Samples.Demos/Snippets). Судя по названию, [SingleElements.cs](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples/blob/master/AngleSharp.Samples.Demos/Snippets/SingleElements.cs) даст мне если не ответы на все вопросы, то пример каноничного кода. Увы, `var emphasize = document.QuerySelector("em");`

[Ok Google, "anglesharp Get element by id"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=anglesharp%20samples&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=anglesharp%20Get%20element%20by%20ID): первые 4 ссылки подсвечены фиолетовым, я там уже был...

**Вопрос: каков, в общих чертах, должен был быть ход рассуждений и действий, способный привести к искомому решению?** (и ни в коем случае не давайте ссылку на доки)).

(Изучить все файлы проекта на GitHub это решение, признаю).

Comment: Если не секрет, который блок вы по Id пытаетесь достать? Мне просто чтобы понять, как по вашему пути размышлению попробовать найти решение.

Comment: id="optionQuotesProductTable1" - это самая большая таблица на странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно простите, но такой огромный поток мыслей - скорей всего является признаком прокрастинации. Вы слишком всё усложняете, буквально на пустом месте. Не надо так много думать - надо было просто сесть и написать код.

Загрузив документ, для разбора таблиц с той страницы, достаточно буквально выполнить по одной строчке:

```
var underlier = document.QuerySelector("#optionQuotesUnderlierTable1") as IHtmlTableElement;
var products = document.QuerySelector("#optionQuotesProductTable1") as IHtmlTableElement;
```

А потом тупо в цикле перебираете их Rows(строки), и у каждого из них вытаскиваете нужные значения из Cells(ячейки).

При этом, во время написания этого кода я не заглядывал ни в Google, ни в какие-то сомнительные статьи на хабре, или "самсебеответы" здесь. Так же я никогда не смотрел примеры использования этой библиотеки.

Почему? Всё просто - у AngleSharp очень интуитивный, самодокументированный код. Кому этого недостаточно - автор снабдил весь код XML-комментариями. Можете просто смотреть подсказки в студии, либо если так хочется читать документацию в MSDN-стиле - натравите на него тот же Sandcastle. А ещё весь код покрыт тестами - это отличный, постоянно обновляемый источник примеров использования тех или иных классов/интерфейсов.

---

Однако, если если хоть немного посмотреть на указанную вами страницу, то во первых, окажется что использовать AngleSharp там не нужно - все данные они выдают и в виде JSON, общаясь из JavaScript-кода с сервером посредством AJAX:

http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Quotes/Option/190/G/J6/ATM?optionProductId=190&strikeRange=ATM&pageSize=500

Соответственно можно просто воспользоватся RestSharp, или каким-нибудь веб-клиентом с связке с JSON.NET, например.

Ну а во вторых, у них есть полноценное API на базе FIXML, которое использовать даже проще:
http://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/CME+Cleared+Trades+API

Comment: Очень благодарен Вам за ответ. Я получил сверх того что хотел. Из уважения к потраченному Вами времени, я перечислю сделанные мной выводы.

Comment: (1) Документация в искомом виде отсутствует (а не я её плохо искал).

Comment: (2) Ситуация не являетя исключением для подобных библиотек - а, скорее, нормой

Comment: (3) Подход "просто писать код" глядя на подсказки VisualStudio не является прокрастинацией по отношению к изучению сторонних библиотек

Comment: (4) Я открыл для себя unit-тесты - крутейшая идея (смейтесь над чайником)

Comment: (5) Узнал про Sandcastle - крутая штука, но теперь я Свободен и для этой задачи он врядли понадобится

Comment: (6) CME что-то даёт бесплатно (честно говоря, сомневаюсь, буду выяснять). У третьих лиц котировки продаются по $5 за 1 месяц по 1 товару

Comment: (7) Перечисленные в конце статьи альтернативные способы получения котировок открыли передо мной пропасть незнания, но и перекинули через неё мостик - чуть позже обязательно разберусь.

Comment: (8) А пока сделаю быстро но как смогу: с помощью WatIn, открою страничку, подожду пока отработают скрипты и буду парсить табличку указанным методом.

Comment: Примите от меня огромную благодарность.

Comment: Одна мелочь не даёт покоя: не заглядывая в google можно узнать о `QuerySelector` и его перегрузках из подсказки. А как можно догадаться про `as IHtmlTableElement`?

Comment: @АндрейВдовенко, просто такое изложение мыслей кажется для меня скорей литературно-писательским, а не программистким. В первый раз, о IHtmlTableElement можно узнать просто запустив код в отладчике, да посмотрев тип значения возвращаемого QuerySelector-ом. В последующие - просто понимаешь, что этот метод всегда возвращает объект у которого есть интерфейс IHtml???Element, да просто смотришь на название HTML-тега, информацию из которого пытаешься извлечь.

Comment: Благодарю, всё ясно.