# C# парсинг html-страницы с помощью AngleSharp

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Подскажите литературу на русском языке по парсингу html с помощью AngleSharp?

Comment: **1.** На этом сайте удаляют вопросы по поиску книг/справочных материалов и т. п. // **2**. Если планируете заниматься программированием, [**очень рекомендую**](https://www.quora.com/How-important-is-English-to-programmers) учить английский; // **3**. Есть [**похожий вопрос**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528434/199934) на этом сайте, может Вам пригодиться. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Спасибо большое за ответ)

Comment: Вам прежде всего нужна литература по снифферам и дебагу чужого JS в браузере) Если все это освоите, то ваш (редкий для Юлий) ум сможет и AngleSharp изучить безо всяких книг и даже почти без гугла.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно парсить с помощью AngleSharp?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528421/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-anglesharp)