# Как изъять текстовое значение из сайта?

Tags: c#, строки, парсер

Мне нужно чтобы приложение,когда форма загружалась принимало, какая музыка сейчас играет на странице пользователя

```
private string getmusic()
{
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    String resp = wc.DownloadString("https://vk.com/id0?149282990");
    String msc = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(resp, @"class=""current_audio_icon""").Groups[0].Value;

    return "Трек : " + msc + " \r\n";
}
```

Приложил код, которым я пытался это сделать

Comment: Ну, вот у вас уже есть код, ошибок не выбрасывает, работает. Что не нравится?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/213987) или [Как правильно парсить с помощью AngleSharp?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528421/213987)

Comment: ошибок нет, а значение не принимает

Comment: А вы представляете, сколько может быть вариантов, что ошибок нет, но значения не будет? Например, профиль закрыт (навскидку три разные причины) или тупо музыка не играет.

Comment: во-первых, мы парсим нашу же страницу

Comment: *1.* Использовать регулярки для работы с HTML - очень большая ошибка! Почитайте данный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/Как-распарсить-html-в-net) и используйте Regex только в крайнем случае!! *2.* Работать с VK нужно путем официального API. Используйте метод [account.getProfileInfo](https://vk.com/dev/account.getProfileInfo) для получения статуса пользователя, сам пользователь пусть включит `Трансляция аудиозаписей` и в ответ вы будете получать [JSON](https://pastebin.com/xXqYcDxp) с текущим треком, даже ссылка на него...

Comment: во-вторых, я проверял с играющей музыкой