# Как правильно спарсить Proxy и сделать разделители?

Tags: c#

Пробую спарсить прокси с сайта

```
public static void ParseProxy(Uri uri)
{
   string pattern = @"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,6}";
   using (var wc = new WebClient())
   {
      wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      var regex = new Regex(pattern);
     Match match = regex.Match(wc.DownloadString(uri));
     while (match.Success)
     {
           builder.Append(match.Value);
           break; // Так и нужно.
     }
   }
}
```

После запускаю метод и вывожу данные которые спарсились:

```
private static StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
private static void Main()
{
    ParseProxy(new Uri("http://xseo.in/freeproxy"));
    Console.WriteLine(builder.Replace(":",", "));
    Console.Read();
}
```

Получаю такой вывод:

> 202.134.180.50, 8080

Как мне получить такой вот результат?

> "202.134.180.50", 8080  - В скобках ""

P.S: Аргументируйте свои минуса!

Comment: `Аргументируйте свои минуса!` - Я минус конечно не ставил, но попробую объяснить за что его могли поставить. **1.** Это по сути не до конца понятна ваша задача, есть стандарт `ip:port`, вы же просите что то странное. **2.** Ваш вопрос не самодостаточен. Для его решения людям надо зайти на сторонний сайт, найти эти данные и начать с ними работать. Почему не приложить сразу то, с чем предстоит работать? **3.** (это касается вопроса и ответа) - вы совершенно делаете все не правильно, вы пытаетесь работать с HTML через регулярки, это очень плохое решение! Ну и **4.** - это дубликат.

Answer (score 1):

Работать с HTML через регулярные выражение- это плохой тон...

Есть [море](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net) готовый библиотек, например [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp/). Не буду повторяться и подробно по его использованию описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528421/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-anglesharp). Просто, написали селектор и получили коллекцию своих эллементов.

Далее из каждого текстового IP вы создаете экземпляр класса `System.Uri($"https://{ваш IP}")`

и можете воспользоваться свойствами `Port` и `Host`и представить результат в желаемом виде.

Как видите, нам не пришлось ничего изобретать руками и мы воспользовались готовыми решениями.

Если вы все таки настаиваете на вашем подходе, то нужно поправить код на такой:

```
Console.WriteLine("\""+builder.Replace(":","\", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем я уже сам додумался =)

Сделал так может кому пригодится =)

```
string proxy = builder.ToString();
string[] tab = proxy.Split(':');
int port = int.Parse(tab[1]);
string ip = tab[0];
Console.Write($"\"{ip}\", {port}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = ".....<font class=\"cls1\">202.134.180.50:8080</font></td><td co...."
var pattern = "(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}):(\d{1,6})";
var replacement = "\"$1.$2.$3.$4\".$5";
var result = Regex.Replace(input , pattern , replacement);
// output = "202.134.180.50".8080
```