# Как вернуть нумерацию в C#?

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

Есть такая разметка:

```
<html>
...
<div class="shop-name">rand</div>
...
<div class="shop-name">rand</div>
...
<div class="shop-name">this</div>
...
<div class="shop-name">rand</div>
...
</html>
```

Как вернуть число 3?
"this" в разметке идет под номером 3.

Спасибо.

Comment: Распарсите HTML при помощи того же `HtmlAgilityPack`, достаньте из документа коллекцию упомянутых div’ов и считайте себе на здоровье

Comment: Спасибо. Я все понял.

Comment: Сие понимать как сарказм?)

Comment: Да ) Нашел вот такую штуку var mach = Regex.Matches(s, "<div class=\"shop-name\">this</div>").Count;. Но отдает число сколько раз конструкция встречается, а не по выборке.

Comment: Вы это бросьте!) Парсить HTML регулярками - очень плохой тон! Сейчас, 5-15 минут и дам ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обязательно познакомьтесь с библиотекой [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)!

Вот пример, который решает Вашу проблему:

```
public static int GetShopIndex(string HTML, string ShopName)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(HTML);
    return doc.DocumentNode
        .SelectNodes("//html//div[@class='shop-name']")? // Выбираем интересующие нас узлы по xpath
        .Select((x, i) => new { Text = x.InnerText, Index = i }) // Комбинируем внутренний текст и номер узла
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == ShopName)?.Index ?? -1;  // Возвращаем индекс узла, текст которого равен заданному
                                                                // Если такого нет - возвращаем -1
}
```

Использование:

```
int i = GetShopIndex("<html><div class='shop-name'>rand</div><div class='shop-name'>this</div></html>", "this");
//i == 1
```

Если отсчет с 0 Вас по каким-то причинам не устраивает, просто добавьте единичку)

Comment: Invalid expression term '.'

Comment: Syntax error, ':'

Comment: @Lebedev: товарищ, Вы у меня вообще двоеточие видите в коде?)

Comment: нет, это какой-то заговор :)

Comment: @Lebedev: прикрепите к вопросу код|скриншот того, что у Вас там делается

Answer (score 2):

Дополненю @Kir_Antipov могу дать ответ на альтернативной библиотеке парсинга — AngleSharp:

```
var html = @"<html>
        <div class=""shop-name"">rand</div>
        <div class=""shop-name"">rand</div>
        <div class=""shop-name"">this</div>
        <div class=""shop-name"">rand</div>
    </html>";

var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.ParseDocument(html);
var elements = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.shop-name").Select(x => x.TextContent).ToArray();

// выводим все
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{element}");
}

// выводим третий элемент
Console.WriteLine($"Третий элемент: {elements[3]}");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылки по теме:

- [Как правильно парсить с помощью AngleSharp?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528421/213987)
- [AngleSharp.Samples](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples)

Нумерация если нужна, то linq такое же:

```
Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Text = x.TextContent })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]