# Как взять данные из сайта и показать на приложении в flutter?

Tags: html, mysql, flutter

Есть сайт , в котором находится данные пользователя. Надо от туда взять эти данные и выводить на приложении в flutter-е. Есть кто этим занимался? Я прочитал в интернете что можно с rest api сделать. Но хочу подробную инструкцию.

Comment: Вопрос слишком широко сформулирован. Непонятна ваша квалификация, что вы уже знаете и понимаете. На текущем уровне ответ будет: спарсить сайт (возможно с авторизацией), вывести в своём приложении. Сайт может не иметь api, поэтому зависит от сайта. В целом -- вам скорее нужно ковырять конкретный сайт, смотреть инструменты парсинга сайтов, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528421/213987 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/213987