# Получение ссылки из html документа

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Не могу понять как получить с помощью регулярных выражений из тега **article** значения свойства **data-file-url** то есть получить ссылку  **https://data/image.png**.

```
<article id="post_299290" class="post-preview blacklisted" data-id="299290"   data-approver-id="35"  data-width="2528" data-height="2924" 
    data-flags=""  data-score="0" data-fav-count="9" data-file-ext="png"  data-normalized-source="" data-is-favorited="false"  
    data-file-url="https://data/image.png" data-uploader-id="39" data-large-file-url="https://data/sample/sample-image.jpg" data-preview-file-url="https://data/preview/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Вы ведь использовали инструменты для работы с html, почему вдруг регулярка? Я на 100% уверен, что у вас приложение тесно связан с html, вы не просто одну строчку разбираете, а значит у вас обязан быть нужный инструментарий, так почему не им??

Comment: Используйте `HtmlAgilityPack` или `AngleSharp`, это и работает быстрее, чем регулярки, и использовать удобнее.

Comment: @aepot я получил  `article`  с помощью  AngleSharp  не понял  как получить  `data-file-url` с помощью AngleSharp.

Comment: [Как правильно парсить с помощью AngleSharp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528421/373567)

Comment: Спасибо всех за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот без проверки тега:

```
(?<=data-file-url=")[^"]*
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5crdk

Из

```
<article id="post_299290" class="post-preview blacklisted" data-id="299290"   data-approver-id="35"  data-width="2528" data-height="2924" 
    data-flags=""  data-score="0" data-fav-count="9" data-file-ext="png"  data-normalized-source="" data-is-favorited="false"  
    data-file-url="https://data/image.png" data-uploader-id="39" data-large-file-url="https://data/sample/sample-image.jpg" data-preview-file-url="https://data/preview/image.jpg"/>
```

найдёт

```
https://data/image.png
```

Answer (score -1):

Можете попробовать расширение для VS Regex Editor - очень помогает для составления паттернов

```cs
var input = "<article id=\"post_299290\" class=\"post-preview blacklisted\" data-id=\"299290\"   data-approver-id=\"35\"  data-width=\"2528\" data-height=\"2924\" \r\n    data-flags=\"\"  data-score=\"0\" data-fav-count=\"9\" data-file-ext=\"png\"  data-normalized-source=\"\" data-is-favorited=\"false\"  \r\n    data-file-url=\"https://data/image.png\" data-uploader-id=\"39\" data-large-file-url=\"https://data/sample/sample-image.jpg\" data-preview-file-url=\"https://data/preview/image.jpg\"/>";
           
var regex = new Regex(@"data-file-url=""(\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b)*""");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);

var links = matches.Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Какая нужна библиотека для `Select`, `System.Linq` и `System.Text.RegularExpressions`подключено и все равно  ошибка!((

Comment: @Vladimir Да вроде больше ничего не нужно. Правда проект .NET Core 3.1(первое попавшеся заупстил) Но все равно верхнее решение оптимальнее моего, так что без разницы