# Помогите спарсить содержимое строчки с помощью AngleSharp в коде C#

Tags: c#, anglesharp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке часть кода HTML странички игра.
Пробую вытащить строчку "Войска игрока Makidonsky", htmldata - это строковая переменная содержащая весть html код.

```
var KodParser = new HtmlParser();

var document = KodParser.ParseDocument(htmldata);

var Stroka = document.QuerySelectorAll("div#ownerLabel");

string element = ???????
```

Comment: [Забавно конечно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQMmn.png), прям вам сам сайт помогает, выдавая [нужный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528434/220553), но вы увы и ах, не хотите искать. Чтож, давайте по порядку: 1. Почему `QuerySelectorAll()`, а не `QuerySelector()`? У вас несколько таких строк в HTML? Думаю нет... Так логично что будет, получить коллекцию, или один конкретный? 2. Неужели вы не знаете, что хотите получить? Вы пишете "вытащить строку", строка это что, как по-другому называется? Текст. Так почему не следуете тогда подсказкам студии? Жмете точку и видите "ага, метод `.Text()`".

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо за ответ, вы были единственный кто пытается помочь.
Касаемо мочему QuerySelectorAll() а не QuerySelector(), в коде несколько таких строк может быть, поэтому QuerySelectorAll().
Далее у меня foreach, просто я не стал подробно объяснять а вижу теперь что нужно.
Предложенный  вариант не работает

```
var KodParser = new HtmlParser();
var document = KodParser.ParseDocument(htmldata);
var stroka = document.QuerySelectorAll("div#ownerLabel");
foreach (var item in Stroka)
{
    string element = item.Text();// ТАК НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!
    string element = item.QuerySelector("div.jewel.label").TextContent;// ТАК НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте "ответы" для дополнения или уточнения по своему вопросу

Comment: `string stroka = document.QuerySelector("div#ownerLabel").TextContent;` Всё, не надо мудрить. Вы оформили дополнение к вопросу как ответ. Удалите этот ответ и перенесите содержимое в вопрос.