# Разбор относительных url в html разметке

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть необходимость получить все относительные пути в HTML разметке. Составил подобное регулярное выражение:

```
@"(?:src|href)=""([^#](?!http[s]*[:])[^/]{2}(([a-z0-9-.]*/)*)([a-z0-9-.]*?[a-z0-9-]*!?.[a-z]{2,4})(?!#)\w*\W*)"""
```

В целом работает как нужно, если использовать аналогичное, например в JavaScript. Якоря типа `#yakor` игнорируются корректно, но есть проблема с якорными ссылками типа `index.html#yakor` в C#, они как раз не игнорируются.

Конструировал в [этом](http://regexpres.narod.ru/calculator.html) калькуляторе, но он для JavaScript.

Comment: Парсить HTML регулярками — не лучшая идея.

Comment: @VladD Почему?.

Comment: Почитайте: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105

Comment: Попробуйте экранировать # так  `\#` или так `\x23`

Comment: @nick_n_a, увы, не помогло.

Comment: @vladD, проблема не столько в парсинге Html, сколько в распарсинге url.

Comment: Эта регулярка даёт одинаковый результат в Яваскрипте и С#. https://regex101.com/r/hQ9bU2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если проблема лишь в разборе ссылки, как сказано в комментарии, то лучше снова-таки не пытаться воспользоваться регулярками, а применить честный класс [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример:

```
var uri1 = new Uri("http://www.google.com/index.html#yakor", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var uri2 = new Uri("/index.html#yakor", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Console.WriteLine(uri1.IsAbsoluteUri); // true
Console.WriteLine(uri2.IsAbsoluteUri); // false
```

---

А для разбора HTML лучше воспользоваться советами [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105).

Comment: В целом `Uri` упростил отсечение абсолютных путей, но пути вида `//site.ru/img.jpg` приходится допиливать вручную.

Comment: @BwehaaFox: А разве это валидный адрес?

Comment: Ну как мне довелось убедиться -да. Как понимаю это некая сокращенная альтернатива `http://` для `src` и `href`