# Регулярное выражение в работе со свойствами HTML объектов

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Получаю HTML код страницы. В нём есть поле вида:

`<input type="hidden" id="regid" name="input_shadow" value="7a312BBBsaKq9rg32asf5ej11djaqvwks">`

Необходимо вытащить из этого поля значение `7a312BBBsaKq9rg32asf5ej11djaqvwks`, используя регулярное выражение. Язык программирования: C#. Требуется совет в организации такого регулярного выражения.

Comment: Регулярки для разбора HTML — плохое средство. Вам [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, но мне нужно именно регуляркой, чтобы научиться брать кавычки в кавычки

Comment: С кавычками-то проще всего, заэкранируйте их при помощи ``\``. Но всё равно использовать регулярки я бы не советовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = @"<input type=""hidden"" id=""regid"" name=""input_shadow"" value=""7a312BBBsaKq9rg32asf5ej11djaqvwks"">";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\bvalue\s*=\s*[""'])[^""']*");
        Match match = regex.Match(input);
        string value = match.Value;
```

Comment: Я бы ещё предусмотрел возможное наличие пробелов до и после знака _равно_, а также одинарные кавычки: `(?<=\bvalue\s*=\s*[""'])[^""']*`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ОК. Нет предела для совершенства :)

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
(?<=value=").+?(?=")
```

В самом коде как-то так:

```
string text = "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"regid\" name=\"input_shadow\" value=\"7a312BBBsaKq9rg32asf5ej11djaqvwks\">";
string regEx = "(?<=value=\").+?(?=\")";
string match = Regex.Match(text, regEx).Value;
```

P.S А не проще ли это интерпритировать как XML и считать значение нужного атрибута по имени?

Comment: хорошо, но... как её вставить?
в это: var sovp = Regex.Match(text, @"....");

Comment: @EgorRandomize, добавил.

Comment: Нужно добавить квантификатор ленивости: `.+?`. Иначе будет захватываться лишнее, до последней встретившейся кавычки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, подправил.