# Как получать результаты AJAX из консольного приложения?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, .net, парсер

Уже рассматривался вопрос [как распарсивать HTML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net), там описано множество разных средств, полезных при парсинге HTML.

А что если на целевом сайте используется AJAX, и часть разметки добавляется или обновляется именно таким образом, как нам получить его результаты?

Как выполнить запрос через `HttpClient` очевидно, вопрос сводится к тому как получать результаты. И парсить сайты, где используются такие запросы.

Comment: Ajax это браузерная технология. Для консольного приложения она сводиться к простым http запросам.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я понимаю, но если надо парсить чужие сайты, то нужно выполнять AJAX-запросы, вопрос сводиться к получения их результатов.

Comment: так как код на странице рассчитан на работу в браузере, в результате получиться, что вы напишите свой браузер. REST и его продолжение HATEOAS были придуманы как раз, что бы можно было создавать разные клиенты. и даже создавать их автоматически.

Comment: Посмотрите в строну  Selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: А можно тем, кто минусует рассказать, что не так? Здесь разрешено делиться знаниями в стиле вопрос-ответ.

Comment: @JK_Action Если хотите, то можете написать ответ об использовании Selenium. Я специально не ограничивался в вопросе конкретной технологией для того, чтобы можно было бы рассмотреть разные и для кого нужно сравнить.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я это понимаю и специально формулировал вопрос так как бы его и задавал новичок (простыми словами), чтобы его легче было бы находить новичкам. Если вы хотите, то можете также на него ответить и привести любые технологии, решающие эту задачу.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я просто вначале не понял вашу цель.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov у вас хороший развернутый ответ. Единственное я бы попытался для решение вашей задачи поискать rest api. Но если такой возможности нет, то придется эмулировать браузер.

Comment: @JK_Action под rest api вы имеете ввиду чтобы сайт имел возможность работы через API?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я бы работал с серверной частью на прямую посылая те самые Ajax запросы из приложения(так определенно меньше накладных расходов), если бы была такая возможность. Другое дело клиентская часть, что-нибудь дополнительно считает, тогда уже без эмуляции браузера не обойтись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хочу сразу оговориться что я в первую очередь рекомендую, посмотреть на наличие на сайте API. У многих сайтов без публичного API есть мобильные версии и непубличное API. Некоторые сайты предоставляют API на платной основе. С некоторыми сайтами можно просто договориться в частном порядке. Парсинг вручную хрупок из-за того, что привязан к представлению данных (которое может как угодно и когда угодно меняться).

---

#### Предисловие

Несмотря на довольно длинный ответ, он сводится к написанию трёх небольших вспомогательных классов, затем пример тоже не совсем простой, зато очень сильно освещает тему парсинга сайтов с Ajax.

## Пример: парсинг моделей машин

Возьмём [каталог машин яндекса](https://auto.yandex.ru/catalog). 
Допустим нам надо получить модели всех популярных марок.

Выберем любую марку и заметим, что в большинстве случаев есть кнопка "Показать ещё 20", но если их меньше 20 — то её соответственно нет.

То есть задача стоит так: нужно посмотреть есть кнопка или нет. Если нет, то забрать те модели, что есть. Если есть, то нажать эту кнопку и дождаться получения результата и т.д., пока кнопки "Показать ещё 20" больше не будет (то есть отобразятся все модели).

#### Предварительные работы

Используйте библиотеку-оболочку, основанную на Chromium, `CefSharp`. Очень подробно её описал [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596363/220571). Устанавливается просто через Nuget пакет.

```
Install-Package CefSharp.OffScreen -Version 57.0.0
```

Скопировав из приведенного мною ответа три класса (`CefSharpWrapper`, `JavascriptException` и `ConvertHelper`), у вас уже есть готов скелет программы, с помощью которой вы можете исполнять любой `JavaScript` прямо из консольного приложения.

---

Также установите `x64` или `x86` в качестве платформы. Платформа `Any CPU` [поддерживается, но требует дополнительного кода](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714).

#### Технические детали обработки результатов Ajax в CefSharp

`CefSharp` позволяет открывать классы C# для обращения к их свойствам и методам из JavaScript.

Мы создадим специальный класс для нашего парсинга, метод `SetResult` которого будем использовать в JavaScript для вызова того же метода в C#.

```
public class JavascriptCallback
{
    // событие, которое срабатывает, когда мы получаем результат из Ajax-вызова
    public event Action OnResult;

    // возвращает объект результата вызова Ajax
    public object Result { get; private set; }

    // метод, который будет вызываться из JavaScript
    public void SetResult(object result)
    {
        Result = result;

        OnResult?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

#### Дополнительный код

Чтобы использовать класс `JavascriptCallback` надо его зарегистрировать до инициализации браузера. Добавьте в класс `JavascriptCallback` поле типа `JavaScriptCallback`:

```
private readonly JavascriptCallback _javascriptCallback = new JavascriptCallback();
```

также в метод `InitializeBrowser` строчку кода

```
_browser.RegisterJsObject(nameof(JavascriptCallback), _javascriptCallback, 
    new BindingOptions { CamelCaseJavascriptNames = false } );
```

после строки

```
_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
```

Помимо добавления класса `JavascriptCallback` нам нужно добавить метод `EvaluateScriptWithCallback` в `CefSharpWrapper` собственно для использования для JavaScript-вызовов, содержащих Ajax:

```
public Task<T> EvaluateScriptWithCallback<T>(string script, bool conditionalAjax = false)
{
    // используется для ожидания вызова SetResult (класса JavascriptCallback) из JavaScript
    TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    Action onResultCallback = null;

    onResultCallback = () =>
    {
        _javascriptCallback.OnResult -= onResultCallback;
        tcs.SetResult(ConvertHelper.ToTypedVariable<T>(_javascriptCallback.Result));
    };

    _javascriptCallback.OnResult += onResultCallback;

    T scriptResult = EvaluateJavascript<T>(script).Result;

    if (conditionalAjax && scriptResult != null)
    {
        tcs.SetResult(scriptResult);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

`conditionalAjax` используется для случаев когда Ajax-запрос может и не потребоваться. Пример: у нас на сайте есть кнопка "Подгрузить ещё N элементов", но её может и не быть, так как всё поместилось на одной странице.

### Написание самого кода

Скажу сразу что для простоты и демонстрации здесь используется jQuery, но код на jQuery будет работать только если на целевом сайте он есть. То же самое справедливо по поводу любой JS библиотеки. Гарантированно будет работать только чистый JavaScript.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        CefSharpWrapper.CefSharpWrapper wrapper = new CefSharpWrapper.CefSharpWrapper();

        wrapper.InitializeBrowser();

        // Получение ссылок на марки
        string[] makeLinks = await wrapper.GetResultAfterPageLoad("https://auto.yandex.ru/catalog", async () =>
            await wrapper.EvaluateJavascript<string[]>(

// Видимые ссылки на марки
@"$('.switchable-list:visible a:visible')
    // Берём атрибут href
     .map((index, element) => $(element).prop('href'))
    .toArray();"));

        foreach (string makeLink in makeLinks)
        {
            string[] models = await wrapper.GetResultAfterPageLoad(makeLink, async () =>
            {
                // Извлечь имя марки
                string makeName = await wrapper.EvaluateJavascript<string>("$('.serp__mark-name').text()");

                Console.WriteLine(makeName);

                return await wrapper.EvaluateScriptWithCallback<string[]>(
@"function getModels() {
    return $('.b-cars_type_search a.b-car > .b-car__title')
        .map((index, element) => $(element).text()).toArray();
}

function isButtonVisible() {
    return $('.b-show-more__button_direction_next > button').is(':visible');
}

function performButtonClick() {
    $('.b-show-more__button_direction_next > button').click();
}

// Добавляем обработчики на Ajax
$(document).ajaxSuccess((event, xhr, settings) => {
    if (settings.url === '/gate/page/loadBlocks') {
        // Если кнопка видимая, то нажать
        if (isButtonVisible()) {
            performButtonClick();
        // Если нет, то извлечь имена моделей
        } else {
            var modelNames = getModels();
            JavascriptCallback.SetResult(modelNames);
        }
    }
});

// Если видна кнопка, то нажимает, если нет, то берём то, что есть
isButtonVisible() ? performButtonClick() : getModels();", true);
            });

            foreach (string model in models)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{model}");
            }
        }

        wrapper.ShutdownBrowser();
    }
}
```

---

#### Результаты программы

В результате в консоли выводится список марок и моделей:

[image: Screenshot results]