# Как получить изображения с Google?

Tags: c#, google-api

Xочу сделать запрос в гугл по слову, получить первое изображение и скачать его получив `byte[]`, как это сделать? На API у них ограничения.

Comment: Нужно пользоваться официальным API. Всё, что не включается в него, не поддерживается гуглом, и наверняка нарушает соглашение об использовании. Нарушать соглашение об использовании нельзя.

Comment: @VladD, если нельзя, но очень хочется...

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Ну это несерьёзно. Я бы на месте заказчика, которому предоставили решение, нарушающее правила использования, не только не платил исполнителю, а ещё и штрафовал.

Comment: @VladD речь о заказчике не шла - может ТС для себя программу пишет

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Ну, я не знаю, какие санкции за нарушение EULA у гугла. В лучшем случае просто выкатит капчу, и код перестанет работать. А в худшем штраф через суд. Если это личный проект, то до суда, конечно, не дойдёт, а вот если коммерческий...

Comment: @VladD каким-же образом гугл узнает, что Вася Пупкин нарушает их правила использования своей программкой для личного пользования?

Comment: ну конечно для себя...

Answer (score 1):

#### Консольное приложения для получения изображений из google.com

Можете воспользоваться библиотекой, оболочкой над браузером, `CefSharp`. Подробно написание вспомогательного кода для неё расписал в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609395/220571).

Вам только надо будет изменить класс `Program` для неё:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        CefSharpWrapper wrapper = new CefSharpWrapper();

        wrapper.InitializeBrowser();

        Console.Write("Введите поисковой запрос: ");

        string searchText = Console.ReadLine();

        string base64 = await wrapper.GetResultAfterPageLoad("https://images.google.com", async () =>
        {
            await wrapper.EvaluateJavascript(
// заполняем тесковое поле
$@"document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = '{searchText}';
// выполняем submit поисковой формы
document.getElementById('tsf').submit()");

            // Ждём когда перейдёт на результаты поиска
            wrapper.WaitTillAddressChanges();

            // Когда страница результатов полностью подгрузится, излекаем картинку
            return await wrapper.GetResultAfterPageLoad(wrapper.Address, async () =>
                await wrapper.EvaluateJavascript<string>(
                    // получаем результаты (атрибут src первой img)
                    "document.querySelector('.rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i img').src"));
        });

        // Так как картинки хранятся в Base64 удаляем заголовок
        base64 = Regex.Replace(base64, @"^data:image/\w+;base64,(.*)", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Превращаем Base64 в массив байт
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        wrapper.ShutdownBrowser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой `selenium`- эта либа позволяет взаимодействовать с браузером.

Подаешь на вход ссылку, затем вбиваешь текст в поиск, переходишь на нужную ссылку, закачиваешь себе страницу, используя `WebClient`, через какой-нибудь `AngleSharp` парсишь эту страницу, получая ссылки, используя `WebClient` закачиваешь.

Может кто-нибудь предложит другой путь...

Comment: Было бы уместно привести пример кода

Comment: Проблема то в том что и кода нет, вот хожу и думаю читаю как это можно сделать, думал может тот кто по опытней знает, но....

Comment: @Alex10934, предлагал привести пример автору ответа...