# Получить количество результатов поиска Google и подсказок всплывающих при вводе запроса

Tags: c#, google-search

Надеюсь вы мне поможете! Собственно, хочу получить количество подсказок при вводе запроса в гугл и после количество всех найденных результатов!

Подскажите как это реализовать?

[image: Скриншот результаты]

[image: Скриншот подсказки]

Comment: Если вам нужно гуглить в консольном приложении, то вам может подойти мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609395/220571) на подобный вопрос.