# Класс или метод для получения html C#

Tags: c#, html, http

Давно интересует: а есть ли где-нибудь универсальный способ получения html-кода всей страницы? Ведь на некоторых сайта нужны куки, где-то еще и авторизация. 
В данный момент использую такой простенький вариант:

```
static string getResponse(string uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586";
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default, true, 8192))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

В большинстве случаев его хватает, но иногда приходится дополнять. Поэтому было бы неплохо заранее иметь готовый вариант, где все учтено

Comment: Возможно вам стоит выбрать инструмент который может разобрать сайт и перевести его в более удобную отладку и возможность автоматом выполнять javascript, путем нажатия кнопок, перехода по ссылкам и т.д. Selenium-например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> а есть ли где-нибудь универсальный способ получения html-кода всей страницы?

Существует слишком много технологий которые нужно учитывать. Есть сайты где есть AJAX подгрузка страницы. Вечная загрузка страницы (например новостная лента в вк) или, скажем, подгрузка таблицы в страницу по нажатию на кнопку.

Как ты получишь полный хтмл страницы одним запросом?

Или, скажем, ты делаешь запрос, добавляешь куки нужные учитываешь аджакс подгрузку по нажатию на кнопки каким-то хитрым макаром (например вызывая JS) или используя виртуальную прокрутку(например вызывая некий JS), а потом тебя перенаправляет для загрузку файла на другой хостнейм. И здесь нужно еще учитывать CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing).

И так далее.

**Короче, что бы полностью обрабатывать все-все-все случаи жизни тебе нужно НАПИСАТЬ СВОЙ ДВИЖОК БРАУЗЕРА**. Ну или использовать уже готовый.

---

## Так что ответ на вопрос:

Есть. *[Точнее есть способ максимально приблизить страницу к той которой видит пользователь]* Используй полноценный движок браузера.  Можно headless (вроде phantomjs или CEF.headless), можно с юаем, например Gecko или CEF. В таком случае ты сможешь получать полный хтмл учитывая все-все-все нюансы которые нужно учитывать при подгрузке ЛЮБОЙ странцы *(собственно, движки браузеров именно для этого и созданны, не так ли?)*

---

Если же ты хочешь в пниципе разобратся какими способами можно сайты парсить, я расписывал основные пути вот здесь:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609646/186752 и там ты сможешь сориентироватся что тебе нужно под твои нужды, а потом уже копать в нужном направлении детали реализации.

Comment: phantomjs - это не метод,а средство

Comment: @YuryBakharev Смотри на сам вопрос: `а есть ли где-нибудь универсальный способ получения html-кода всей страницы?` а где говорилось про метод в вопросе? PhantomJS это способо получить html код всей страницы с полной его обработкой.

Comment: В заголовке вопроса

Comment: @YuryBakharev я думаю по заголовку понятно, что автор ищет любой способ (т е если библиотека такое может, то его тоже устроит)

Comment: @YuryBakharev Окей, метода НЕ существует. Зато существует способ. Я его дал, при чем конкретный. В чем претензии к ответу?

Comment: Не понравилась сама трактовка в конце, может вводить в заблуждение. А именно слово "Есть", можно было написать метода нет, но есть способ, опять "ошибка молотка" вроде как.

Comment: @YuryBakharev то есть ответ правильный, но минус за формулировку?) Понятно. Удачки :) как по мне, то формулировка вполне правильная. Особенно учитывая жирный текст и вообще весь контекст до того куска которы тебе не понравился по каким-то личным причинам.

Comment: Фактически словом "Есть", вы даёте неправильный ответ. На некорректно составленный вопрос.

Comment: @YuryBakharev Я даю ответ на то, что автор имел ввиду. И ответ и вправду "есть". Дотаточно просто внимательно почитать что я написал. То что этот ответ тебе лично не нравится, это не значит что это не ответ. Проблему "универсальности" ТСа решает? Решает. Значит это ответ. Просто он не нравится лично тебе.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Прочитайте статью на мете "Ошибка молотка"

Comment: Так-то используя даже полноценный браузерный движок может потребоваться сделать какие-то действия. Скажем, по нажатию на какую-то кнопку шлется AJAX-запрос, который в свою очередь возвращает на страницу какой-то список товаров.=> Все равно нужно изучать саму страницу и писать код => нельзя открыть страницу браузером и получить код всей страницы в некоторых случаях.

Comment: @iluxa1810 использование готового движка это максимально универсальный способ получить максимально полный хтмл с учтением ВСЕХ подводных камней. Универсальнее способа не бывает. Да, есть сайты где нужны доп.действия. Но через готовый движок их будет сделать проще, чем по-одному добавлять функционал к своему личному "универсальному" методу создавая свой личный движок с блекджеком и...) Или ты считаешь что есть способ универсальнее?

Comment: @Andrew, не, я считаю, что с текущей постановкой вопроса, ответом будет "Универсальных методов нету". Так как веб сам по себе динамичный и в любом случае придется изучать сайт через консоль разработчика и т д.

Comment: Ваш ответ, стал более понятен , тем, кто плохо знаком с данными технологиями.

Answer (score 2):

Если сайт требует авторизации (вероятно, на самом деле имеется в виду аутентификация?) и поддержки cookies, необходимо добавить код, который реализует это. Другого варианта нет. Если сайт использует стандартную basic authentication, это можно сделать так:

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("admin","123","example.com"); 
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache(); 
myCache.Add(new Uri("example.com"), "Basic", myCred);
CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/");
request.Credentials = myCache;
request.CookieContainer = myContainer;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Для сайтов, где аутентификация осуществляется POST-запросом нестандартного вида, универсального способа нет и не может быть.

Comment: есть еще аутентификация через строку в самом запросе вида `http://username:password@example.com/yourpage` . А еще можно использовать REST библиотеки что бы писать значительно меньше низкоуровневого кода для этих же действий.

Comment: @Andrew насколько я понимаю, это разновидность basic authentication (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#URL_encoding), которая была отменена  RFC 3986 из-за ее небезопасности и сейчас не очень актуальна

Comment: а про то что она отменена, я и не знал. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, такого метода не существует так как JavaScript может на ходу добавлять/удалять элементы => для каждого сайта нужен свой отдельный подход, изучая работу сайта через консоль разработчика.

Comment: В anglesharp есть возможность работать и с Javascript, если добавить `.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss().WithJavaScript()`, так что общего подхода может и нет, но учесть можно многое.

Comment: Да, но в вопросе, как я понимаю идет речь о возможности написать какой-то 1 универсальный метод, который везде будет работать=> на каком-то сайте может потребоваться прожать на все кнопки, что бы получить "полный" HTML.