# c# Firefox Gecko вставить текст в input

Tags: c#, firefox, webbrowser, gecko

Использую  WebBrowser Gecko.
Нужно вставить текст в вставить текст в input на сайта.
Код:

```
<input class="input" type="Text" name="Author" value="">
```

Как это сделать?
Спасибо

Comment: если цель автоматизация - то нужно использовать селениум + геко драйвер.  Если цель другая - то вероятннее всего ты делаешь что-то странное и не совсем тем путем, который нужен. Но вообще можно запустить JS скрипт на странице который введет текст. Сработает с вероятностью в 100%.

Comment: @Andrew, а селениум можно встроить в само приложение? 
Частично нашел решение - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683027/getelementsbyname-geckofx, но как вставить текст в поле так и не понял

Comment: А зачем тут вообще движок браузера?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, для автоматизации.

Comment: Какой? Вот скажите мне, зачем вам UI, если всякие формочки и кнопочки, это простые POST/GET запросы на сервер? Почему не работать сразу с сервером? Скажите хоть одну причину, из за которой для решения вашей задачи, нужен целый браузер?

Comment: Классическая [XY-ошибка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567). На ваш вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ. Как минимум потому, что вы держите в секрете свой код, и не говорите, зачем это всё вам нужно. А рассказать надо как минимум потому, что скорее всего вы выбрали неверный или сложный путь решения своей задачи, и здесь подскажут правильный и легкий. Отредактируйте вопрос, внесите в него максимум информации, тогда шансы получить понятный и развернутый ответ значительно возрастут.

Comment: EvgeniyZ прав, наиболее вероятнее что конечного результата лучше всего будет добиться через запросы. В принципе что бы +- понять что именно нужно тебе лично можно просмотреть вот этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609646/186752 . Вероятнее всего он поможет сориентироваться.

Comment: По поводу селениума - можно встроить селениум. Но браузер - все равно будет открываться отдельным окном. Можно вообще не открывать если использовать  phantomJS. Но вообще если это не автоматизированное тестирование - то лучше удержаться по-дальше от селениума, в общем и целом. Но т.к. неясны цели - то и ответ расплывчастый.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, 
При публикации этого комментария был выполнен следующий запрос:
Request URL:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1177207/comments
Form Data
comment:  EvgeniyZ, ТЕКСТ
fkey:578c502f8b0284012aa866a5afd4e67ac691a036cf70c8a5fc7ba8ccddb52b99

Как при работе с POST/GET получить fkey?

И второе - капча

Comment: Так надо анализировать ресурс, чтоб понять как он работает. Вам вон выше сказали, что без описания конкретной задачи мы вам не поможем. Где-то, такие значения в HTML странице, где-то, их дает доп. запрос на нужный адрес, где-то, их генерирует JS. Вариантов много, надо искать. Также и капча, смотря как она работает, под это и надо подстраиваться. Я не говорю, что браузер это плохо, я говорю, что браузер - это в 90%, как съездить на танке за хлебом. P.S. Отправил сообщение, отследил ваш `fkey`, вон он в HTML страницы, там JSON данные с ключом (`StackExchange.init`) .