# Как сделать поиск в гугл по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть текст бокс куда вписывается запрос, к примеру "Кошки". И ниже кнопка Найти. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки он делал этот запрос в гугл и выводил первые 100 результатов под кнопкой "Найти" допустим в специальной форме. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ок, задача есть, хорошо, но от нас вы что хотите, чтоб написали за вас? Где ваши попытки?

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я сделал:
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
 
        }

Это конечно самая легкая часть, но тут же и проблема, я не знаю как реализовать сам поиск. Какие запросы отправлять и парсить первые 100 результатов?

Comment: @aepot через что реализовать запросы(там вроде несколько "библиотек" для этого) и как спарсить первые 100 результатов

Comment: Сайты, это http запросы, за запросы в C# отвечает только один компонент - `HttpClient` (другие устарели). Также вам нужно понять как работают привязки, как правильно работать с данными в WPF, также что такое JSON и что такое HTML и как с ними работать. Только вот вы выбрали не самый лучший сайт для практики, ибо google имеет защиту.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ с html и json у меня был опыт. А что насчет официального апи от гугла? им можно пользоваться или оно устарело

Comment: Да пользуйтесь на здоровье, вариантов у вас масса, хоть HTML парсите.

Comment: Помогу вам [чуть чуть](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hlfVYF), остальное уж давайте сами, а то реально сейчас все за вас напишем...

Comment: Спарсить может не получиться, Гугл умный и не позволяет приложениям работать с поиском минуя рекламу, которую он показывает. Он просто не позволит вам использовать себя, выдаст капчу, еще что-нибудь. Но (да простит меня @EvgeniyZ) пример как отпраить запрос и распарсить есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, я только что попробовал сам написать, вот что вышло
https://pastebin.com/FTKH18y3
Правда не работает(хаха) смотрю в чем проблема

Comment: из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8): _Мы не рекомендуем использовать `WebClient` класс для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` класс._

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не можете подсказать как в вашем примере увеличть результат? То есть больше 10 ссылок, как там

Comment: Ищите запросы, которые отправляет браузер, смотрите как там реализована подгрузка контента.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и потом воспроизвести это через HtmlAgilityPack ?

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack` - это работа с HTML, если данные в HTML, то да.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а есть ли где-то статьи на русском по HtmlAgilityPack ? Просто документация на английском, а аналогов на русском нет

Comment: Учите английский, без него программисту не как. Так что я вам лично с этим не помогу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я знаю что английский важен и я +- хорошо ориентируюсь, но намного легче когда статья и все объяснения на русском

Comment: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/373567), [Распарсить HTML в .NET и выжить](https://habr.com/ru/post/273807/)

Comment: См. также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609395/240512

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115520/discussion-on-question-by---------).