# Есть ли в CefSharp замена функций selenium для поиска по xpath?

Tags: c#, selenium, cefsharp

Типо с помощью selenium можно делать прикольные штуки. Типо:

```
IWebElement element = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a"));
```

Но selenium для тестирования? Если у заказщика не будет определеного браузера, то все...
Есть Cef, но там нету таких функций как в selenium, есть какой-то компромисс?
У меня есть html страница, есть ли какая-нибудь версия selenium которой надо просто давать html на растерзание?

Comment: apparently not: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CEF является браузером, а не инструментом автоматизации. Встроенного функционала поиска элемента и взаимодействия с этим элементом в CEF нет.

Стоит так же сказать что часть функционала будет недоступно в подобной автоматизации и прийдется делать костыли. Например запускаемый JS имеет некоторые ограничения для секьюрности, поэтому на часть кнопок невозможно будет кликнуть при помощи JS.

Детали как обойти это вот в этом вопросе на англоязычном SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680724/cefsharp-webpage-element-click

---

Т.к. вопрос изменился, я дополню: Ты можешь в свою программу встроить безюайный браузер phantomJS. То есть качаешь селениум, качаешь нюгет phantomJS и пишешь свою программу которая будет взаимодействовать. Получаешь и селениум и запуск на любой машине независимо от установленных браузеров.

---

UPD: Если цель - парсинг/кравлинг - используй лучше AngleSharp. С остальными вариантами можно ознакомится по ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609646/186752

Comment: Мне не нужно кликать по элементам, нужно получать textContent элементов.

Comment: если ты хочешь только парсить - есть методы по-лучше)))

Comment: Какие другие методы???

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609646/186752