# Парсинг сайтов в .NET

Tags: c#, html, .net, парсер

Пытаюсь распарсить сайт через `AngleSharp`.

Для этого написал метод:

```
void  TravelHtml(IHtmlElement element)
{
    if (element.Children.Length!=0)
    {
        foreach (var child in element.Children)
        {
            TravelHtml((IHtmlElement)child);
            if (child.LocalName == "img")
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText(child.Attributes["src"].Value + "\n");
                continue;
            }
            richTextBox2.AppendText(child.TextContent + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Которому на вход подаю Body.

Проблема в том, что если один тег внутри другого тега, то получаю задвоенные значения.

Например, внутри `<p>` тега находится текст в теге `<b>` .

Сейчас получается, что я получаю текст с тега выше, а потом когда спускаюсь в child, то опять же получаю этот текст. Мне нужно получать текст с самого низкого уровня.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Или может быть мне какие-то теги игнорировать в обходе?

Так же можете предложить альтернативную библиотеку.

**UPD:**

На вход подаю вот это:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000233
EndHTML:0000001392
StartFragment:0000000269
EndFragment:0000001356
SourceURL:http://www.opengost.ru/1016-gost-19325-73-peredachi-zubchatye-konicheskie.-terminy-opredeleniya-i-oboznacheniya.html
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><p style="color: rgb(14, 14, 14); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);">Стандартизованные термины набраны полужирным шрифтом, их краткие формы - светлым, недопустимые термины - курсивом.</p><p align="center" style="color: rgb(14, 14, 14); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);"><b>1. ТЕРМИНЫ, ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ И ОБОЗНАЧЕНИЯ</b></p><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
```

И в итоге получаю вот это:

> Version:0.9 StartHTML:0000000233 EndHTML:0000001392
>   StartFragment:0000000269 EndFragment:0000001356
>   SourceURL:http://www.opengost.ru/1016-gost-19325-73-peredachi-zubchatye-konicheskie.-terminy-opredeleniya-i-oboznacheniya.html
>
> Стандартизованные термины набраны полужирным шрифтом, их краткие формы
>   - светлым, недопустимые термины - курсивом.1. ТЕРМИНЫ, ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ И ОБОЗНАЧЕНИЯ
>
> Стандартизованные термины набраны полужирным шрифтом, их краткие формы
>   - светлым, недопустимые термины - курсивом.
>   1. ТЕРМИНЫ, ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ И ОБОЗНАЧЕНИЯ
>   1. ТЕРМИНЫ, ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ И ОБОЗНАЧЕНИЯ

Т.е дубли из-за того, что один тэг вложен в другой тег, а Text() примененный к вышестоящему элементу извлекает текст и с ниже стоящих=> при рекурсивном обходе у меня дублируется информация.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/186999)

Comment: а что именно ты разбираешь и что хочешь получить на выходе?

Comment: приведи небольшой пример Html который ты разбираешь, пример результата, который ты получаешь сейчас, и пример результата который ты хотел бы получать, для этого Html

Comment: Ну так а какой должен быть результат? что например выводить если кроме одного тега b Будет еще текст? `<p>text <b>b text</b> text1</p>`

Comment: @Grundy, <p>text1<b> text2</b> text3</p> . Вы наверное это имели ввиду? Тогда text1 text2 text3.

Comment: а почему _text1 text2 text3_? а не только _text2_?  а если внутри `b` Будет еще тег span?

Comment: в принципе достаточно пройтись по верхнему уровню элементов, например `p`  и брать сразу их text, без захода внутрь. Либо непонятна логика того, какой из текстов должен выбираться

Comment: @Grundy, но тогда я могу упустить текст из ссылки, так как Text не возвращает саму ссылку. Вот ради таких случаев я и рекурсивно и обхожу Body, что бы детально проанализировать.

Comment: так надо определиться **зачем** ты обходишь и что хочешь получить. Иначе, проверка всех возможных нюансов будет слишком трудоемка

Comment: @iluxa1810 Ваша задача просто получить чистый текст (без тэгов) всего документа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вот так вот решил свою задачу:

```
void NodeTraveling(INode node, StringBuilder sb)
{
    foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        switch (childNode.NodeType)
        {
            case NodeType.Text:
            {
                sb.Append(childNode.NodeValue));
                break;
            }
            case NodeType.Element:
            {
                if (childNode is IHtmlImageElement)
                {
                    var imageElement = (IHtmlImageElement)childNode;
                    sb.Append("<img>" + imageElement.GetAttribute("src") + "</img>");
                    continue;
                }
                NodeTraveling(childNode, sb);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить у нужного элемента текст с помощью JavaScript есть свойство `innerText`. То есть средствами JavaScript можно получать, к примеру, весь текст страницы (без разметки). Для этого достаточно  `document.documentElement.innerText`.

Для того, чтобы загрузить саму страницу и исполнить JavaScript используйте библиотеку `CefSharp`, код-обёртку для которой я подробно описал в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596363/220571). То есть по сути, написав 2-3 класса, вы можете просто исполнить в консоли тот JavaScript, который вам нужен, затем просто перенести код в программу.

Сам код вызова будет выглядеть так (если нужен текст со всего документа):

```
var url = "http://www.opengost.ru/1016-gost-19325-73-peredachi-zubchatye-konicheskie.-terminy-opredeleniya-i-oboznacheniya.html";

string text = await wrapper.GetResultAfterPageLoad(url,
    async () => await wrapper.EvaluateJavascript<string>(
    "document.documentElement.innerText"));
```

Comment: Эм.. Это вообще к вопросу не относится.

Comment: @Qwertiy Очень даже относится, так как сказано "Также можете предложить альтернативную библиотеку.". И это способ получить текст всего документа или определённого контейнера. А значение `url` взято из `SourceURL` вопроса.

Comment: 1. Ему вроде не надо выполнять скрипты. 2. innerText (который, к тому же, на js должен быть textContent'ом) даст в точности ту же строку, которая приведена в вопросе как нежелательная. Вывод: ответ не решает проблему, описанную в вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет `innerText` не вернёт дублирования, вернёт чистый текст. Вы похоже мой код не выполняли и не пробовали даже. А выполнение скрипта через CefSharp тоже является решением данной задачи.

Comment: Если бы он брал текст `html`, у него бы тоже проблемы не было, а он рекурсивно обходит все элементы.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, его задача получить текст и всё. Для этого и нужно получить `innerText` нужного элемента.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52591/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vadim-ovchinnikov).

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант, перенести

```
richTextBox2.AppendText(child.TextContent + "\n");
```

в

```
if (element.Children.Length!=0)
{
  ...
}
else
{
  /* сюда */
}
```

Однако замечу, что тут могут потеряться куски текста из таких конструкций:

```
<p>Начало <span>середина</span> конец</p>
```