# Зарегистрироваться на сайте средствами C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Есть сайт https://ekb.zarplata.ru/resume

Чтобы просмотреть отдельно взятое резюме,
надо перейти на его страницу. Но я не могу этого сделать - прав нет. Нужно регистрироваться. Там нужно оставлять контактные данные, чего я делать бы не хотел. Можно ли с помощью *C#* как-то преодолеть этот барьер?
То есть без регистрации все же просмотреть страницу с резюме в браузере?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50713/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 0):

Вам по сути нужно программное управление браузером для авторизации, затем нужно просто извлечь интересующие вас данные.

Поэтому я делал бы так.

1. Зарегистрировался бы на сайте вручную.
2. Написал бы программу с помощью `CefSharp`. Это программная оболочка над Chromium. Подробнее в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net/596363#596363).
3. Затем заполнял бы поля для логина/пароля с помощью JavaScript.
4. Если на сайте есть капчи, то использовал бы сервис антикапчи (к примеру https://rucaptcha.com/).
5. Затем с помощью JavaScript брал интересующие меня данные. Подробности в той же ссылке.

Скажу сразу скептикам, что это работает и я так не один сайт распарсивал.

Можно, конечно, и по куче раз регистрироваться таким способом, но для данной задачи это не имеет смысла. Просто залогиньтесь и всё.