# Значение ИЛИ в регулярном выражении

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

В html коде встречаются несколько видов

> ```
>  class="r, class="s, class="f
> ```

мне нужно регуляркой вытащить только до класса `s` или `f`
пытаюсь так :

```
 Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"</span>(.*?)class=""s?f?");
```

но оно не подходит, оно и понятно, ведь ? - 0 или 1 раз. Как мне сделать, чтоб брала до `class="f` или `class="s` минуя `r`.

Класс `class="r` иногда встречается по середине текста и в результате регулярка берет не верно

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ :
Есть такой код :

```
</span>213123123123ваывыаыва class="s
</span>213asdasasdadыва class="r saddas class="f
</span>2321sad class="f
```

Мне нужно вытащить все, что между `</span>` и `class="s` или что между `</span>` и `class="f` .

Comment: а к какой строке это все должно применяться?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net)

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, вообще строка как-то на совсем плохой Html похожа :-)

Comment: @Lolidze, то есть вторую строку вообще не должно найти? или наоборот полностью ее найти?

Comment: вторую строку должна взять так :
213asdasasdadыва class="r saddas

Comment: тобишь class="r игнорировать

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, вроде работает? [http://regexstorm.net/tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%2fspan%3e%28.*%3f%29class%3d%22%5bsf%5d&i=%3c%2fspan%3e213123123123%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8b%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b0%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0+class%3d%22s%0d%0a%3c%2fspan%3e213asdasasdad%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0+class%3d%22r+saddas+class%3d%22f%0d%0a%3c%2fspan%3e2321sad+class%3d%22f)

Comment: Да в этом вопросе ничего неясно.

Answer (score 1):

`[fs]` - любой из перечисленных символов:

```
<\/span>(.*?)class=\"[fs]
```

Тест: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/imD

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew исправил

Comment: @Crantisz Желательно вместо `(.*)` брать `(.*?)`, чтобы не взяло прошлое совпадение.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov исправил