# Как с помощью регулярок добавить html class?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть html-текст. Привожу кусок.

```
<i><img src="http://cs425224.vk.me/v425224222/8870/r2lyLPEqXmY.jpg" width="730" height="461" /></i>
```

Как с помощью регулярки найти все ссылки на изображения в тексте, и добавить туда тег `class="img-responsive img-center-xs"`

Как я понимаю надо с помощью srting.IndexOf прицепиться к тегу, но не совсем понятно как.

Comment: Наверное, вам сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105

Answer (score 0):

Если все ссылки на изображения начинаются с "<img src", то вы можете сделать замену даже без регулярных выражений, просто изменив "<img src" на "<img class="img-responsive img-center-xs" src".

В HTML не имеет значения, в каком порядке указаны параметры тэга.