# Работа с регулярными выражениями в с#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть переменная типа `string`, там записан большой текст. У меня есть регулярное выражение `Regex regex = new Regex(@"<div class=\""b-opinions-main-2__text\"">.+</div>");`, которое хранится в переменной типа `string`. 
На месте .+ должен быть текст. Как мне записать .+ в переменную?

Comment: Либо вам сюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , либо вам стоит перефразировать задачу

Comment: Есть строка, в строке есть подстроки '<div class=\""b-opinions-main-2__text\"">Привет Мир </div>' '<div class=\""b-opinions-main-2__text\"">пока Мир </div>' , я составил регулярное выражение '<div class=\""b-opinions-main-2__text\"">.+</div>', как мне найти все эти подстроки и записать их в другую переменную, чтобы я потом из них мог достать 'Привет Мир' или 'Пока Мир'

Comment: Тогда я дал верную ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML нужно парсить с помощью соответствующих инструментов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net).

Теперь по существу: ту часть регулярного выражения, которую необходимо получить, нужно заключать в неэкранированные круглый скобки. `(...)` – *захватывающая группа*. Есть именованные и численные захватывающие группы. Вот пример последней: допустим, есть ваша регулярка, нужно то, что находит `.+` - заключаете эту часть в скобки. В коде:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"<div class=\""b-opinions-main-2__text\"">(.+)</div>");
//                                                               ^^^^
var resultaty = reg.Matches(str)                  // Находим все совпадения
                  .Cast<Match>()                  // Получаем список объектов Match
                  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value) // Получаем нашу подстроку из группы №1
                  .ToList();                      // Конвертируем в список.
```

Эта реглярка взята из ТС только как образец. В реальном коде не советую использовать. Пользуйтесь [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Да, можно пытаться её улучшить и даже написать `@"(?s)<div\s+class=""b-opinions-main-2__text"">(.+?)</div>"`, но и эта регулярка в один (не)прекрасный момент может дать сбой, т.к. регулярки не предназначены для парсинга HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать метод [Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx), для получения всех совпадений из класса [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    string g = "<div class=\"b-opinions-main-2__text\">qwerty</div>";
    var regExp = new Regex("(?<=<div class=\"b-opinions-main-2__text\">).+(?=</div>)");

    var matches = regExp.Matches(g);
```

Тип переменной `matches` — [MatchCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx). Данный тип не позволяет использовать `LINQ` методы, но можно проходить с помощью цикла `foreach`.

```
foreach (var m in matches){
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

p.s. Либо используйтесь `@`, либо экранируйте кавычки, но не все сразу.

Comment: *Данный тип не позволяет использовать LINQ методы* - очень даже позволяет.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew если сделать приведение типов — да. Напрямую — нет.