# Регулярное выражение, которое бы искало слово (н,м)(а,я)вка между <span> и <br>, захватывая при этом и теги <a>

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Прошу вашей помощи. 
Имеется строка с html кодом, которая выглядит следующим образом

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>***@conference.***.us - 25.06.2017</title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/chatlogs.css"/> -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
///....
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: right;">
<a style="color: rgb(170, 170, 170); font-family: monospace;" href="../../../">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="roomtitle">tulpae-flood</div>
<a class="roomjid" href="xmpp:***@conference.***.us?join">***@conference.***.us</a>
<div class="logdate">25.06.2017<span class="w3c"><a class="nav" href="../../2017/06/24.html">&lt;</a>
<a class="nav" href="./">^</a> <a class="nav" href="../../2017/06/26.html">&gt;</a></span>
</div>
<br/>
...
<a name="00:00:00" href="#00:00:00" class="ts">[00:00:00]</a>
<span class="mn">&lt;Nick&gt;</span>
" Шаблон "
<br>
<a name="00:01:00" href="#00:01:00" class="ts">[00:01:00]</a>
<span class="mn">&lt;Nic2&gt;</span>
" Шаблон2 "
<br>
<a name="09:43:11" href="#09:43:11" class="ts">[09:43:11]</a> 
<span class="mn">&lt;Hankl&amp; Blr&gt;</span> 
О, Навка, Навка!
<br/>
```

Пытаюсь написать регулярное выражение, которое бы искало слово (н,м)(а,я)вка между `<span>` и `<br>`, захватывая при этом и теги `<a>`.

Вот такая попытка успехом не увенчалась:

```
preg_match_all("/<a name=\"(.*?)\" href = \"(.*?)\" class=\"ts\"> (.*?) </a> 
<span class=\"mn\"> (.*?) </span> (Н|М)(а|я)вк.*?/i", $html, $search);
```

Буду очень благодарна, если кто-то откликнется и подскажет!

Comment: можно примеры слов,  которые нужно найти?

Comment: @Alex `(Н | М) (а | я) вк.`. То есть, если я неправильно написала, то первая буква либо н, либо м в любом регистре, далее либо а, либо я, потом "вк" и буква со склонением (а, у, е и т.д.):) Спасибо, что отозвались

Comment: @Alex ну и пример целого слова - Навка, Мявку, Нявки etc

Comment: @Kate Gurman Разве в искомом тексте есть такие слова?

Comment: @KateGurman пожалуйста напишите пример, в котором есть нужный текст и тот результат, который вы хотите увидеть

Comment: @Alex `<a name="09:43:11" href="#09:43:11" class="ts">[09:43:11]</a> <span class="mn">&lt;Hankl&amp; Blr&gt;</span> О, Навка, Навка!<br/>`. Желаемый результат - отыскать эту строку среди тысячи других:) Целиком, с таймштампом и спаном

Comment: Извините за оффтопик, но что за странный выбор слов? :)

Comment: @rjhdby ну, всего лишь стало необходимым пропарсить логи конференции, чтобы отыскать сообщения, затрагивающие человека, ничего удивительного:)

Comment: разбор html лучше всего выполнять специальными парсерами (например, [simplehtml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/))

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю @mymedia. HTML нежелательно парсить регулярными выражениями, они подвержены ошибкам из-за того что HTML сложен и может быть невалидным. Гораздо лучше решают задачу специальные парсеры. Пользоваться ими в чем-то даже проще, чем регулярками.

Comment: Вот на английском: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Вот про .Net, но там хорошо объясняется суть проблемы: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net)

Comment: Спасибо, уважаемые, в сторону simpl html смотрела. К сожалению, текст, который необходим для проверки, не заключен в теги, а возможности найти предстоящие перед текстом теги я не нашла с помощью либы.

Comment: @KateGurman вот об этом и стоило задать вопрос — как найти текст по тегам перед ним. :)

Comment: @Kate Gurman мой самый первый пример как раз и искал текст `между` тегами.

Comment: @Эдуард `"/<a.*(Н|М)(а|я)вк.*<(\/span|br\/{0,1})>/sgUu"`?

Comment: @Kate Gurman `'~(?!</span>)(?:н|м)(?:а|я)вк(?:.+)(?!<br/?>)~ium'`

Comment: @Эдуард preg_match_all захватывает лишнее, начиная с позиции совпадения и до конца...

Comment: @Kate Gurman я проверял на вашем тексте из первого поста, и только что добавил в искомый текст столько же строк html-кода (т.е., удвоил число строк искомого текста) -- всё отработало корректно.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Кажется нашел ответ, но если будут вдруг ошибки не кидайте камни)))

Это регулярка:

`#<a name((?!<\/span>).)*<\/span>((?!<br\/?>).)*(н|м|а|я)вк.*?<br\/?>$#mius`

Это кусок кода `php` с шаблоном текста автора:

```
<?php

    $html = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>***@conference.***.us - 25.06.2017</title>
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/chatlogs.css"/> -->
            <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            ///....
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div style="text-align: right;">
            <a style="color: rgb(170, 170, 170); font-family: monospace;" href="../../../">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="roomtitle">tulpae-flood</div>
            <a class="roomjid" href="xmpp:***@conference.***.us?join">***@conference.***.us</a>
            <div class="logdate">25.06.2017<span class="w3c"><a class="nav" href="../../2017/06/24.html">&lt;</a>
            <a class="nav" href="./">^</a> <a class="nav" href="../../2017/06/26.html">&gt;</a></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            ...
            <a name="00:00:00" href="#00:00:00" class="ts">[00:00:00]</a>
            <span class="mn">&lt;Nick&gt;</span>
            " Шаблон "
            <br>
            <a name="00:01:00" href="#00:01:00" class="ts">[00:01:00]</a>
            <span class="mn">&lt;Nic2&gt;</span>
            " Шаблон2 "
            <br>
            <a name="09:43:11" href="#09:43:11" class="ts">[09:43:11]</a> 
            <span class="mn">&lt;Hankl&amp; Blr&gt;</span> 
            О, Навка, Навка!
            <br/>';

    $reg = '#<a name((?!<\/span>).)*<\/span>((?!<br\/?>).)*(н|м|а|я)вк.*?<br\/?>$#mis';

    preg_match_all($reg, $html, $matches);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $matches[0][0];

?>
```

А это вывод `echo '<pre>'; echo $matches[0][0];`:

```
<pre>
    <a name="09:43:11" href="#09:43:11" class="ts">[09:43:11]</a>
        <span class="mn">&lt;Hankl&amp; Blr&gt;</span>
            О, Навка, Навка!
    <br>
</pre>
```

Comment: работает как часы ) Только у вас в шаблоне лишние экранирующие слэши. С ними тоже работает, но они в шаблоне просто не нужны.

Comment: @Эдуард буду благодарен если скажете в каких местах?

Comment: @Эдуард Если вы про это `\/` то я их всегда экранирую потому что часто люди пишут регулярки так `/regexp/`.

Comment: вот ваш шаблон без лишних слэшей: `'#(<a name)(((?!</span>).)*)(</span>)(((?!<br/?>).)*)((н|м|а|я)вк.*?)(<br/?>)$#mis'`

Comment: Спасибо большое за код, @RazmikGalstyan! Ваш код на приведенном примере работает так, как и должен, однако, в моей строке возвращается пустой массив. Подозреваю, что это из-за того, что строка содержит и другие элементы помимо тех, что в примере?

Comment: Обновите вопрос и я пересмотрю ответ.

Comment: подправте под (Н|М)(а|я) - ложные срабтывания есть

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Обновила! Очень благодарна. Возможно, стоит просто обрезать строку только до текста?

Comment: @KateGurman я пробивал регулярку на вашем обновленном тексте и все работает как и в предыдущем, не знаю что вы там делаете что получаете пустую или не правильную строку. если так необходимо могу и видео скрина сделать и показать.

Comment: Минус за разбор HTML регулярками. Для этого есть специализированные парсеры.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вопрос задан так что человеку нужно регулярка, и ответ правильный. Выбор как разобрать `html` не мы решаем, вопрос задан по другому

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan человеку нужна не регулярка, а результат. То что она регулярку просит — это частный случай [ошибки XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy?s=1|2.2303), а ваша задача — объяснить, как правильно парсить HTML.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Значит скажите автору вопроса пусть грамотно задает вопрос, а ответ именно то что просил автор в вопросе.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan автор задает вопрос с позиции своих знаний. Если бы она знала, как правильно делать, то наверняка и не спрашивала бы. А вы в данном случае выступаете как эксперт. Ваш ответ, притом отмеченный галочкой, подразумевает, что парсить регулярками — нормально и хорошо. А на деле это не так. Четыре минуса на ответе как раз это и обозначают.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Для этого я и говорю все эти комментарии сказали бы ей, и она бы изменила вопрос, или вы измените вопрос, вы же модератор, а не минусуете ответы, если после изменения вопроса я бы не изменил ответ, то ваш `-1` считал бы верным, все ровно я считаю что вы не правильно сделали, это мое мнение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, @RazmikGalstyan, на приведенном примере регулярка отрабатывает как надо... Буду уже копать, что же такого лишнего в строке лежит

Comment: @NickVolynkin И еще можете дать пример ответа например как найти нужную часть с помощью `PHP DOMDocument`? или есть вообще другой способ о котором я не знаю? не просветите ?