# Как генерировать html через c#

Tags: c#, html

Нужно генерировать простенькую страничку, в которой будет меняться заголовок, немного текста и добавляться, убавляться элементы списка. Как делать в html-знаю, но в c# пытаюсь записать такую инфу в файл, определяя кавычки слешами - документ записывается в файл правильно, и в блокноте все теги, закрывающие открывающие и кавычки на месте, но браузер не видит в этом тексте разметку. Может дело в том, что кавычки при обрамлении их слешем не такие как нужно встают?

**UPD: проблема была возможно вызвана тем, что html код  html в с# visual studio при вставке получает лишние пробелы между спецсимволами (<>), и я считаю что это требует обсуждения и внимания а не является банальной опечаткой.**

[Файл html который получается](https://yadi.sk/d/AVMmmdtf3LZdak)

```
 string content2 = System.String.Format(
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<title> Документы {0} {1}</title>" +
            "< link href =\"../../favicon.ico\" rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x icon\" />"+
            "< link href =\"../../favicon.ico\" rel=\"shortcut icon\" 
type=\"image/x-icon\" />"+
            "< link rel =\"stylesheet\" href=\"../../css.css\" 
type=\"text/css\" />"+
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "{0} {1}" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>", date, textBox_title.Text);

        #endregion

        File.WriteAllText("index.html", content2);
```

Comment: Что значит `браузер не видит в этом тексте разметку`?

Comment: Удалите пробелы: `<link`, тогда нормально открывается

Comment: @Андрей значит что браузер открывает это как текст, не преобразую в команды гипертекста

Comment: @Андрей да чтоб меня... копировал же с первоисточника без пробелов!

Comment: *html код html в с# visual studio при вставке получает лишние пробелы между спецсимволами* — багрепорт им отправьте.

Comment: Когда копируете (вставляете) в IDE, сперва напишите две кавычки: `""`, поставьте курсор между ними, потом жмите Ctrl+V. Тогда IDE не будет пытаться отформатировать вставленное.

Comment: Как вариант, если после вставки содержимое было отформатировано (добавлены пробелы и т. п.), достаточно сразу же нажать Ctrl+Z (один раз!) - форматирование будет отменено.

Answer (score 5):

В соответствии со [спецификацией HTML п. 12.1.2.1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags) первый символ открывающего тега - символ `<`, а следующие символы должны представлять имя тега.

Таким образом, пробел после `<` делает HTML невалидным, и, поэтому, он не воспринимается браузером. Следует удалить пробелы, например:

```
<link href = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, лучше использовать какой-нибудь HTML [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net), который позволяет работать c HTML подобно XDocument.