# Как получить отсюда значение \d*?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
 string st = Convert.ToString(Regex.Match(str, "id=\"user_online\">\\d*").Groups[0]);
```

Как получить отсюда значение \d*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int wholePhraseGroupIndex = 0;
const int numberGroupIndex = 1;

// Комилируем регулярное выражение для ускорения поиска
Regex regex = new Regex("id=\"user_online\">(\\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

// Сравниваем строку с паттерном
Match match = regex.Match(str);

// Проверяем, что строка совпала
if (!match.Success)
    throw new FormatException("Строка имеет неверный формат: " + str);

// Извлекаем содержимое скобок
string numberStr = match.Groups[numberGroupIndex].Value;

// Парсим значение
int number = int.Parse(numberStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Куда должна записаться переменная?

Comment: @deced В `st` :D
`Groups[0]` - весь совпавший результат
`Groups[1]` - содержимое первой скобки
и т.д.

Comment: А зачем вообще нужно `Convert.ToString`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew абсолютно ненужно, не стал менять, чтобы код оставался похожим на авторский и ему было понятно - в чём изменения.

Comment: Так опишите изменения и уберите лишнее. Будет понятнее и ценнее.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew не вопрос, детализировал. :)

Answer (score 2):

Надежный способ получения части совпадения - именованные группы:

```
var str = "id=\"user_online\">33";
var match = Regex.Match(str, "id=\"user_online\">(?'usersCount'\\d*)");
if (match.Success)
{
    var usersCount = match.Groups["usersCount"].Value; // "33"
}
```

Альтернативный вариант - использование механизма positive lookbehind. В вашем случае - поиска таких `\d*`, перед которыми стоит тэг:

```
var match = Regex.Match(str, "(?<=id=\"user_online\">)\\d*");
if (match.Success)
{
    var usersCount = match.Value; // 33
}
```

Ну или можно обернуть `\d*` в скобки и достать `Groups[1]`, но этот подход может поломаться при переписывании регулярки в будущем.

Не забывайте, что [парсить HTML регулярными выражениями - плохая идея. Есть гораздо более простые способы извлечь значения из тэгов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net).

Comment: сколько лет живу на свете, а не знал, что в регулярках есть именованные группы. :D