# В чем ошибка в парсере AngleSharp и как вообще работает QuerySelector?

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Царство_(биология)");

var div = doc.QuerySelector("h1.firstHeading");
Console.WriteLine(div);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете в шарады поиграть? Мы не знаем где ошибка в вашем коде, вы нам скажите :)

Comment: просто ничего нет, отладчик не показывает значения

Comment: а что он должен показать?

Comment: заголовок собственно

Comment: Может [дубликатом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528421/Как-правильно-парсить-с-помощью-anglesharp) ?

Comment: там нет примеров

Comment: у вас по идее div - это элемент или набор элементов, после того, как вы его получили, у него внутри что то есть? Он нашел что то? Смотрели отладчиком?

Comment: да, значение null , тип angelsharp.Dom.Ielement

Comment: Вы пытаетесь парсить строку, которая является _адресом_ (url), а нужно на вход методу `Parse` передавать _html_.

Comment: Вообще, у Википедии есть [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) - можно получать разную информацию, используя его, вместо парсинга страниц.

Comment: понял вас, александр, тогда встречный вопрос : "Как c помощью anglesharp скачать этот html? "

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что вы не посмотрели какого типа у вас div - а он типа IELement, а значит нужно брать его `.Text()`:

```
void Main()
{
    var parser = new HtmlParser();
    var document = parser.Parse(@"<body><h1 class='firstHeading'>Биология</h1></body>");

    var element = document.QuerySelector("h1.firstHeading");
    var title = element.Text();
    title.Dump();
}
```

Если лень лезть в [документацию](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki), то хотя бы просто посмотрите набор полей в отладчике, они все интуитивно понятные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как скачать url при помощи anglesharp можете посмотреть в этом вопросе: [Чтение содержимого сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719872/213987)

Кстати, если смотреть страницу не в браузере (где исходный код страницы сильно модифицирован загруженным Javascript), а скачанный anglesharp - то видно, что h1 имеет совершенно другой id.

Поиграйтесь на досуге:

```
var url = @"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)";
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss();//.WithJavaScript();
var document = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(url).Result;

var element = document.QuerySelector("h1#section_0");

if(element == null)
{
    "No such element".Dump();
}
else
{
    var h1Title = element.Text();
    h1Title.Dump();
}
```

(Для закомментированного кода потребуется нугет-пакет AngleSharp.Scripting.Javascript)

Как работает QuerySelector. Этот вопрос рассмотрен в [нашем вопросе-faq по anglesharp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528421/213987), читайте и перечитывайте от фразы "Чтобы понять, что надо писать, повторюсь, вам надо выучить CSS селекторы." - это и есть как раз ответ на ваш вопрос "что писать в QuerySelector".