# AngleSharp Вылетает ошибка с js

Tags: c#, anglesharp

```
 var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss().WithJavaScript();
```

Если не использую javascript все норм, если нет,то ошибка

```
System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Сообщение = Не удалось загрузить тип "AngleSharp.Services.IScriptingProvider" из сборки "AngleSharp, Version=0.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e83494dcdc6d31**".
  Источник = AngleSharp.Scripting.JavaScript
  Трассировка стека:
   в AngleSharp.JsConfigurationExtensions.WithJavaScript(IConfiguration configuration)
```

Comment: Пардон муа, я скопипастил код из старых своих примеров и не видел, что там ещё старая библиотека. Спасибо, что оформили отдельным вопросом, если кто в старых примерах на so будет спрашивать - будет закрывать дубликатом на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас примеры на устаревшую версию AngleSharp (Там где рекомендовалась старая проверенная AngleSharp.Scripting.Javasctipt) сейчас надо грузить AngleSharp.Js и использовать не `.WithJavaScript()` а `.WithJs()`

> If you are using a new version of AngleSharp then you must use
>   AngleSharp.Js. AngleSharp.Scripting.JavaScript is not supported and
>   only works with versions pre 0.10.

https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/829