# C#: Парсинг конкретного значения из html строки

Tags: c#, html, парсер

Имеется html строка:

```
<input id="mail" onclick="select(this);" data-original-title="Р’Р°С€ РІСЂРµРјРµРЅРЅС‹Р№ Email Р°РґСЂРµСЃ" class="mail opentip" value="yinoto@p33.org" data-placement="bottom" title="" type="text" readonly>
```

Как мне можно получить значение value, (оно всегда разное)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В проекте наводишь курсор мыши на `References`, жмёшь правую кнопку, выбираешь `Manage NuGet Packages`, в строке поиска напиши [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net). Подключай эту библиотеку.

Предположим, твой `html` находится в текстовом файле. Я написал пример, который получает из файла код и парсит его. Понятно, что можно распарсить и другими способами, но я думаю, что `html` нужно парсить созданными для этого библиотеками. Тем более эта библиотека осилила отдельный тег, ей не нужно на вход подавать полный `html` документ.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace HtmlParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToFile = Path.Combine(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Source.txt");

            string source = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);

            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(source);

            var value = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes["input"]
                .Attributes["value"]
                .Value;

            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```