# Искажение русских символов при получении кода элемента с помощью WebClient.DownloadString

Tags: c#

Получаю исходный код страницы через

```css
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(site);
```

Русские символы превращаются в такую кашу -

> Р СѓСЃСЃРєРёРµ СЃРёРјРІРѕР»С‹РѕРЅРё С‚Р°РєРёРµ СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёРµ

Как это можно задекодить? Что это за кодировка?

Comment: измени кодировку `client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: Вроде, Хеадер прочитать в котором будет указана кодировка, а затем прочитать с нужной кодировкой

Comment: @Lolidze спасибо, помог.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, сделал.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Класс, спасибо!

Comment: @iluxa1810: Подождите, а разве это кодировка? У вас там вроде ContentType. Он включает кодировку?

Comment: @VladD, Я проверил. Если ее не указывать, то будут кракозябры. Однако, если присвоить ее в клиенте, то все нормализуется.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Интересно, не знал.

Comment: @VladD, в дебагере видно, что там "text/html;charset=UTF-8" . Как раз и кодировка есть.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ага, ContentType таки содержит кодировку. Понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измени кодировку `client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 2):

Как-то вот так:

```
 var site = @"https://www.ulmart.ru";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            WebRequest request=WebRequest.Create(site);
            var response= request.GetResponse();
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, response.ContentType);
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(site);
```

Сначала мы отправляем запрос сайту и получаем от него ответ. В ответе мы можем прочитать его заголовок. В заголовке указан тип контента(В данном случае `text/html;charset=UTF-8`). С помощью этих данных мы можем корректно скачать строку.

А если использовать какие-то [библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net) для парсинга Html, то они на ходу сами, по идее, преобразуют кодировку.

Answer (score 1):

Проверять разные кракозябры, на  ход преобразований, можно например тут https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/

В вашем случае `client.Encoding` получил значение по умолчанию, т.е. кодировку по умолчанию в ОС, в которой выполняется код, для руссифицированной Windows, это кодировка 1251. 
И надо добавить в ваш код `client.Encoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` перед скачиванием строки.