# Парсинг HTML и разбор script по полочкам

Tags: c#, парсер

Если спарсил HTML код и в нём есть что подобное:

`<script>"text1":"value1","text2":"value2","text3":"value3"</script>`

Как вытаскивать нужные значения ?

Пользовался раньше подобным вариантом:

```
String Response = wc.DownloadString(ssilka);
Rate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Response, @"""text1"":([^<]+),""value1""").Groups[1].Value;
```

Но сейчас, встречается две одинаковые строки в одном `<script></script>` и регулярка вытаскивает в итоге огромную часть кода.

Как вытаскивать правильно из того что находится в `<script></script>` ?

Comment: Вы разбираете HTML регулярками?

Comment: @VladD когда как... Но не знаю как нужно поступать в этом случае(

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться готовыми решениями. Например, есть [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) - библиотека на Java, которая предназначена для разбора HTML-страниц, позволяя извлечь необходимые данные, используя DOM, CSS и методы в стиле jQuery. Есть [порт на C#](https://github.com/matarillo/dcsoup). 
[Здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/jsoup.php) можно ознакомиться с примерами (на Java).

---

Прежде чем задавать новые вопросы, настоятельно рекомендуется поискать

[ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/203589](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/203589)

[stackoverflow.com/a/18157325/5674802](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157325/5674802)

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто разбить с помощью `String.Split(char)` и перебрать в цикле, что-то вроде

```
using System.Xml;
...//прочий код программы
XmlNode script;//наш xml-узел
...//парсинг до xml-узлов

string[] sriptTextValuePairs = script.InnerText.Split(',');//побьём содержимое xml-узла на множество пар-подстрок
foreach(string tvPair in sriptTextValuePairs)//перебор пар
{
  string[] pair=tvPair.Split(':');//разобьём пару
  string text=pair[0].Trim('"');//вытащим значения
  string value=pair[1].Trim('"');
  ...//делаем что-то
};
```