# Как вытащить значение между закрытым и откртым тегом С#

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, htmlagilitypack

Доброе время суток!
C помощью HtmlAgilityPack получаю строку из исходного кода:

```
 <div class="b-auth">
<a class="b-link" href="/personal/" >10000031007</a>(<span class="b-user-acc b-user-acc_type_deb">Аванс: </span>113,04 | <a class="b-link" href="/?logout=yes" >Выход</a>)
</div>
```

Вопрос, как вытащить значение 113,04 с помощью регулярок или любым другим способом.

Comment: На всякий случай: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/10105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярки - это хорошо, я сам их люблю и часто применяю.

Однако, html - *нерегулярная* грамматика, поэтому *регулярные* выражения плохо подходят для его парсинга.

Чтобы гарантированно не ошибиться, можно сперва с помощью средств HtmlAgilityPack получить текстовые узлы, а уже их распарсить регэксами.

```
// Узел, содержащий приведённый в вопросе html.
var divNode = ...

var textNodes = divNode.ChildNodes.OfType<HtmlTextNode>();

foreach (var node in textNodes)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(node.Text, @"\d+,\d+");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value); // нужное нам значение
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для разнообразия либ могу посоветовать автору вопроса ещё обратить внимание на `AngleSharp`.

Answer (score 0):

регулярное выражение **/\d+,\d+/**

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот такой шаблон попал в искомое число:  `(?<=[>])[\d][\d,]*(?=\s\|)`

Однако, лучше все таки такие вещи парсером HTML делать.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь!
Получилось сие чудо. 
Чуть-чуть доработал под себя.

```
//Перевел в текст через HtmlAgilityPack и вабрал значение до 1 000,00
// Узел, содержащий html.
var data = ...;
var match = Regex.Match(Convert.ToString(data.InnerText), @"\d+.\d+,\d+");
```