# c#. System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser и код текста для IFrame

Tags: c#, iframe, webbrowser

Использую стандартный System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser для загрузки и отображения одной вебстраницы. WebBrowser эмулирует 11 версию IE. Страница имеет IFrame и отображается нормально.

Мне необходимо получить полный HTML код страницы с содержимым IFrame, но эти элементы пусты. В полноценном IE html-код можно видеть. Текст кода пробую получать следующими двумя способами:

```
public String HtmlDocumentText {
  get { return webBrowser.DocumentText; }
}

public String DomDocumentText {
  get {
  // REM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640236/converting-htmldocument-domdocument-to-string
  var document = webBrowser.Document;
  var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;
  var content = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.outerHTML;
  return content;
  }
}
```

Мне кажется, что проблема заключается в ограничениях безопасности для этого элемента, потому как следующий код вызывает ошибку доступа:

```
var frames = webBrowser.DocumentTestToDelete.Window.Frames;
var frame1 = webBrowser.DocumentTestToDelete.Window.Frames[0];
var document1 = frame1.Document;
```

Ошибка:
    Access Denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Замечу, что мне удалось получить код IFrames при помощи JavaScript:

```
string jCode = "var iframe = document.getElementById('frame-id'); var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; innerDoc.documentElement.innerHTML";
Object html = webBrowser.WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { jCode });
```

Но это не то что надо, хотя я мог бы такой подход использовать, но с большими трудозатратами. Может быть есть способ заставить WebControl отдавать полный html вместе с содержимым IFrame?

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `DocumentText` возвращает то, что вы просите - код документа. Код содержимого iframe'ов в него не входит, поскольку iframe - это больше, чем просто механизм подстановки одного HTML внутрь другого (*). Чтобы получить документ вместе с содержимым iframe'ов, единственный способ - пройти по всем iframe'ам, взять их содержимое (например, через интерфейс `MSHTML.IHTMLIFrameElement3`) и подставить в исходный документ. Понятно, нельзя получить содержимое, если iframe смотрит в другой домен.

Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebBrowserTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        public String DomDocumentText
        {
            get
            {
                var document = webBrowser1.Document;
                string returnstr = "";

                MSHTML.IHTMLDocument3 doc3 = null;
                MSHTML.HTMLDocument new_doc = null;
                MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = null;
                MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection elems = null;
                MSHTML.IHTMLDocument3 new_doc3 = null;
                MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection elems_new = null;

                MSHTML.IHTMLDocument3 child_doc = null;
                MSHTML.IHTMLElement content = null;
                MSHTML.IHTMLElement content_new = null;
                MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection elem_col = null;


                try
                {
                    doc3 = (MSHTML.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;//исходный документ

                    new_doc = new MSHTML.HTMLDocument();//копия документа

                    doc2 = new_doc as MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2;
                    doc2.write(webBrowser1.DocumentText);//создаем копию документа

                    //получаем все iframe в документе и его копии...

                    elems = doc3.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

                    new_doc3 = new_doc as MSHTML.IHTMLDocument3;

                    elems_new = (new_doc3).getElementsByTagName("iframe");


                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (MSHTML.IHTMLIFrameElement3 elem in elems) //для каждого iframe...
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            child_doc = elem.contentDocument as MSHTML.IHTMLDocument3;
                            elem_col = child_doc.getElementsByTagName("body");
                            if (elem_col == null || elem_col.length == 0) { i++; continue; }

                            content = (MSHTML.IHTMLElement)elem_col.item(0);
                            string str = (content).innerHTML;//получаем содержимое iframe
                            content_new = elems_new.item(i) as MSHTML.IHTMLElement;
                            (content_new).outerHTML = str;//заменяем iframe на его содержимое                  
                            i++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //для iframe, URL которых в другом домене, будет исключение
                            //HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Can't process iframe " + i.ToString());
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            //Очистка ресурсов, задействованных в цикле...
                            if (child_doc != null)
                            {
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(child_doc); child_doc = null;
                            }

                            if (elem_col != null)
                            {
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(elem_col); elem_col = null;
                            }

                            if (content != null)
                            {
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(content); content = null;
                            }

                            if (content_new != null)
                            {
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(content_new); content_new = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }//end foreach


                    returnstr = new_doc.documentElement.innerHTML;
                    return returnstr;
                }
                finally
                {                
                    //Окончательная очистка ресурсов...
                    if (doc3 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc3);
                    if (new_doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(new_doc);
                    if (doc2 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc2);
                    if (elems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(elems);
                    if (new_doc3 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(new_doc3);
                    if (elems_new != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(elems_new);
                    if (child_doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(child_doc);
                    if (content != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(content);
                    if (content_new != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(content_new);
                    if (elem_col != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(elem_col);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(DomDocumentText);
        }
    }
}
```

Для использования нужно подключить библиотеку COM-объектов IE (в Visual Studio  <kbd>Добавить ссылку</kbd> -> <kbd>СОМ</kbd> -> <kbd>Microsoft HTML Object Library</kbd>, либо вручную указать файл mshtml.tlb).

**Примечания**

(*) - Для iframe браузер создает отдельное окно внутри основного окна, которое может, в общем случае, отображать не HTML, а документ другого типа. Поэтому в модели DOM свойство `InnerHTML` у iframe соответствует не его содержимому, а замещающему тексту для браузеров без поддержки iframe, который можно поместить внутрь тега iframe (что редко используется в наше время).

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. но мне не понятно, откуда у вас IHTMLIFrameElement3? Какую библиотеку вы для этого используете? Я использую C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\CommonMicrosoft.mshtml.dll версии 7.0.3300.0

Comment: @SergejLoos "Добавить ссылку" - "СОМ" - "Microsoft HTML Object Library" (если в списке такого нет, поищите на диске файл mshtml.tlb) Это библиотека COM-объектов IE, DLL из нее будет сгенерирован автоматически и помещен в папку проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения своей проблемы я исползовал JavaScript, указанный в вопросе:

```
documentHtml = webBrowser.DomDocumentText; 

// extract frames content (by frame id)
var framesAsHtmlElements = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe"); 
foreach(HtmlElement frame in framesAsHtmlElements) {
    String id = frame.Id;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) == false) {
        string jCode = "var iframe = document.getElementById('" + id + "'); var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; innerDoc.documentElement.innerHTML";
        String frameHtml = webBrowser.WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { jCode }) as String;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(frameHtml) == false) {

            // ((?im)<iframe(([.]|[^/]|\r\n|\r|\n)*?id=["']frame-id["'](.|\r\n|\r|\n)*?)(/>|</iframe>)+?)
            Regex regEx = new Regex(String.Format(@"(<iframe(([.]|[^/]|\r\n|\r|\n)*?id=[""']{0}[""'](.|\r\n|\r|\n)*?)(/>|</iframe>)+?)", id), RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
            Match match = regEx.Match(documentHtml);
            if (match.Success) {
                int pos = match.Index;
                int length = match.Length;

                documentHtml = documentHtml.Substring(0, pos) // before <iframe>
                    + "<iframe" + match.Groups[2].Value + "/>"
                    + frameHtml
                    + "</iframe>"
                    + documentHtml.Substring(pos + length); 
                    ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Решения для работы с HTML с использованием Regex могут быть ненадежными / трудноподдерживаемыми, см.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/240512. Лучше использовать парсер, в DOM найти все элементы iframe и заменить значение OuterHTML, довольно просто делается без сложных регулярок.

Comment: Я это понимаю, поэтому и пытался использовать DOM, но с первого раза не получилось. А надо было срочно закрыть пробелему. А с ручным добалением COM и автоматической генерацией interop классов попробую несколько позже. Спасибо за наводку