# Ошибка при разборе EntityName

Tags: c#, linq2xml

Есть следующий код

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString("https://habr.com/top/");
```

Далее пробую создать XML-документ:

```
XDocument xdoc= XDocument.Load(html);
```

выдаёт ошибку:

> "Ошибка при разборе EntityName"

строка в документе, на которой вылетает ошибка:

> *{Text, Value="/* Font Face Observer v2.0.13 - В© Bram Stein. License: BSD-3-Clause */(function(){'use strict';var f,g=[];function
>   l(a){g.push(a);1==g.length"}*

пробовал через Parse(html) - всё равно не могу разобрать эту строку.
может кто подскажет, как мне обрабатывать такого рода строки чтобы записывать в XML - а потом проходить по узлам. 
или нужно писать свой некий обработчик строк используя `XMLReader` и `XMLReaderSettings`?

**Не использую** библиотеки `AngleSharp`  и прочие, **пытаюсь разобраться** с `LinqToXml`.

Comment: Ну дык там же не будет валидного XML. Придется разобраться с парсерами HTML: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/218063

Comment: Будет ли правильным скопировать только элементы между <body> </body> и записать  их в XML?

Comment: Нет, читайте комментарии к этому ответу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450586/218063