# Не могу понять как правильно экранировать регулярку в коде

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Пишу сниппет для того чтобы регуляркой код из письма вытянуть, но не могу разобраться с экранированием, перечитал кучу всего, но так ничего и не получилось, если кто даст ссылки на дельную статью по этому поводу или поможет разобраться что я делаю не так, буду благодарен.
Заранее спасибо.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
Tab tab = instance.AllTabs[1];
tab.SetActive();
instance.ActiveTab.FindElementByAttribute("div","innerhtml","Spam","regexp",9).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
instance.ActiveTab.FindElementByAttribute("button","class",@"Button\ sidebar__action\ is-visible","regexp",0).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
instance.ActiveTab.FindElementByAttribute("nh-stream-item","innertext","NZDating","regexp",0).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
instance.ActiveTab.FindElementByAttribute("nh-stream-item","innertext","NZDating","regexp",0).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
var dom = instance.ActiveTab.DomText;
var regex = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(dom,@"(?<=<td><font\ face="arial,helvetica"><b>).*(?=</b></font></td>)");
if (!regex.Success) throw new Exception ("Не найден код на почте"); 
project.Variables["link_confirm"].Value = regex.ToString();
tab = instance.AllTabs[0];
tab.SetActive();
```

Comment: [Дельная статья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/184217).

Comment: Вы как-то вообще не стой стороны подошли к своей задаче, иметь dom document и при этом парсить регуляркой  !?

Comment: Тут всё верно, только проблема с кавычками, а это даже не относится к регуляркам. `@"(?<=<td><font face=""arial,helvetica""><b>).*(?=</b></font></td>)"`

Answer (score 0):

**Двойные кавычки** (`"`) - заменяем на одинарные (`'`)(если возможно), либо ставим обратный слеш (`\`) перед знаком - получаем `"\""`.

**Обратный слеш** (`\`) - экранируется добавлением еще одного слеша в начале. - `"\\"`

В итоге из вашего кода мы можем сделать следующее:

`(?<=<td><font\\ face=\"arial,helvetica\"><b>).*(?=</b></font></td>)`

Функционал сами подправляйте, но саму суть экранирования думаю поймете.