# Парсинг html-документа средствами C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Каким образом можно спарсить html-документ без сторонних библиотек таких как AngleSharp и т.д.?

Comment: Без сторонних никак

Comment: А именно Regex...

Comment: Средствами C# нельзя, но можно использовать входящую в Windows Microsoft HTML Object Library (пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738668/240512).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так вроде регулярные выражения не следует использовать для парсинга?

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000 Ну вы сами изобретаете велосипед, без заточенных специально под это дело инструментов пытаетесь что то сделать... Я лично вижу два варианта - регулярки и парсить как xml и то и то довольно плохо.

Comment: Ни регулярками, ни `xml` вы ничего не распарсите. В HTML есть теги, которые не закрывают, например `<br>`, `xml` парсер сломается на таком. Парсить HTML регулярками, это все равно что парсить `c#` код регулярками.

Comment: @Zergatul Ну тогда с эталонной закрывашки про регулялярки убрать наверно надо? Я лично пробовал регулярками, геморно, тупо, но возможно! По поводу XML отличия есть, да... По этому я и назвал все эти методы "плохими", но с определенными задачами они справятся.