# Парсинг html с помощью регулярных выражений C#

Tags: c#

Провожу загрузку html страницы

```
html = client.DownloadString(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
```

потом регулярным выражением пробую вырезать часть строки

```
string s1 = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
string s2 = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();
Regex regex = new Regex(s1 + @".*" + s2);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(html);
if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                    html1 = match.Value;
                    MessageBox.Show(html1);
                }
```

Самое интересное что если копируешь кусок кода и присваиваешь переменной html то регулярное выражение отрабатывается а если производишь загрузку как выше указано то совпадение не находится

Comment: Ну вы сравните в чем отличие загруженного html и вставленного вами вручную. Ну а так, категорически не советую вам регулярками парсить html. Почитайте лучше [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/Как-распарсить-html-в-net/420355#420355).

Comment: <div class="price" id="bx_117848907_1279_price">
                                     337 руб.                                    </div>
           <div class="price discount">
            <strike>481 руб.</strike>

Comment: В том то и суть что не в чем s1="_price">"   а s2="руб."

Comment: + @Evgeniz, не надо руками этого делать, Cef поможет, или родной для C# контрол от ИЕ, но надо подгрузить COM объект.

Comment: Может проблема в спец символах? при присваивании я их экранирую а при загрузке страницы что-то выходит не так

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вам может помочь [ОнЛайн regexp](http://regexstorm.net) для подбора выражения.

А вообще лучше не использовать regexp, а взять готовый HTML фреймворк, например Cef, это по сути Хром браузер.. :)

Comment: Разобрался! Необходимо было удалить все переносы строк

Comment: вам надо было привести полную строку regexp, а не `s1 + @".*" + s2`, что там, можно только догадываться..

Answer (score 0):

Проблема совершенно в другом, и это кодировка вашего `HTML` вероятно вы предполагаете что разметка отвечает сл. символу `"` а в реальности `&quot;` и другие `&amp;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;`, `&apos;` для избежания подобных символов в вашем html достаточно указать:

```
html = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
```

И только после этого работать с исходным кодом, и да regex не лучший способ парсить html.