# HTML C# | Parser

Tags: c#, парсер

Требуется спарсить данное значение из g_steamID средствами C#
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это всё, что вам нужно, то почему бы просто поиском подстроки не сделать `String.IndexOf`? А так тот же [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: Дело в том, что я вообще не понимаю как парсить даже тэги, а отдельные строки тем более)
Мне надо спарсить эти циферки из g_steamID

Comment: Вам ссылку дали, будьте добры, зайдите по ней. Или документация не для вас?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/Как-распарсить-html-в-net

Answer (score 1):

Ну если у вас есть html от которого нужен только steamID, то:

```
string html = "<script>    g_steamID = \"7786578\" ddd"; // Для примера
int startIndex = html.IndexOf("steamID");
startIndex = html.IndexOf('\"', startIndex);

string steamID = "";
while (startIndex < html.Length && html[startIndex + 1] != '\"')
    steamID += html[++startIndex];
// steamID = "7786578" (Без кавычек)
```

Код написан втупую, но основной посыл должен быть понятен. Можно и через регулярку, но думать сейчас уже не в состоянии.

Comment: Мне надо скачать html код по ссылке https://steamcommunity.com/id/blyagdeya
И спарсить значение

Comment: @Zabeg о-о-о, а это уже беда. Там и false может быть, и в другом месте и виде этот steamID. Тут уже основательно прорабатывать нужно. Сходу такое уже не сделать. Учите язык. Работу со строками и т.д. Попробуйте сами что-то и если уже вопросы сюда приходите. За вас решать такого рода задачи вряд ли будут.

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/id/blyagdeya?xml=1
А если такого рода?
Стим айди на 2 строке всегда

Comment: @Zabeg спарсить XML гораздо проще, задайте это отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в пределах html старницы профиля есть ещё один script-текст, который вроде бы всегда содержит **SteamId**. Парси тогда из него, раз в первом скрипте может быть `false` вместо целевого значения. Во втором скрипте он всегда инициализирован реальным значением. Забирай хоть регуляркой, хоть `String.Split`, чем душе угодно.

Если дело не обходится одним только **SteamId**, то гораздо удобнее сразу юзать какую-нибудь либу. Вон вверху советовали HtmlAgilityPack. Я предпочитаю для таких вещей [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp). Пример дал ниже. Но для парсинга единственного значения это конечно как из пушки по воробьям.

```
using AngleSharp.Dom.Html;
using AngleSharp.Parser.Html;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowQuestion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void ButtonParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string steamId = await ParseSteamId();
        }

        private async Task<string> ParseSteamId()
        {
            // Грузим нужную нам страницу
            string url = "https://steamcommunity.com/id/blyagdeya";
            string html = await LoadHtml(url);

            // Создаём экземпляр парсера из AngleSharp
            HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
            IHtmlDocument document = parser.Parse(html);

            // Парсим нужный нам элемент html страницы. Div класса 'responsive_page_template_content' является уникальным в пределах всей страницы
            // и включает в себя целевой скрипт, текст которого уже всегда(*) включает SteamId.
            // *Я просмотрел 10 случайных профилей, для всех случаев SteamId был инициализирован реальным значением, никаких 'false'.

            var targetScriptWithSteamId = document.QuerySelector(".responsive_page_template_content > script"); // Селекторы тут https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/
            string scriptText = targetScriptWithSteamId?.TextContent;
            string id = scriptText.Split(new string[] { "steamid\":\"", "\",\"" }, 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];

            return id;
        }

        private async Task<string> LoadHtml(string url)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            string source = null;

            if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                source = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            return source;
        }
    }
}
```