# Поиск строчки в тексте и индексирование повторяющихся

Tags: c#, html, веб-программирование

Имеется код html страницы, в котором есть такие теги как "span itemprop=\"name\">"
Я без труда нахожу значение, но проблема в том, что находит значение самого первого тега. Как сделать, что б все "span itemprop=\"name\">" проиндексировать, и получать нужное значение через индекс?

Comment: Хотите я сразу помечу это как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/220553), закроем и забудем про этот вопрос, сойдет? Не хотите, то давайте сразу сообществу больше данных, чем парсите HTML, ваши попытки, тогда мы начнем искать проблему в вашем коде. Сейчас этот вопрос я лично расцениваю как `как распарсить html`.

Comment: загружаю html  string response = webClient.DownloadString(url);  string s = response;
                string r = pr.searchOtDO(s, "span itemprop=\"name\">", '<');// нахожу функцией поиска в файле тег - читаю его до символа, что в середине - идет в r. Но как мне сделать чтобы следующий тег взял?

Comment: Иии... У вас получается `string` с неким текстом, дальше действия? Вот вы пишите `Я без труда нахожу значение` - как вы это делаете?

Comment: те считываю значение самого первого тега, но как узнать значение 2го 3го и так далее?

Comment: что такое `searchOtDO`? От куда он у вас? Вы используете что то для обработки html?

Comment: функция поиска  public string searchOtDO(string data,string start,char finish)
        {
            string zapros = start;
            int zlen = zapros.Length;
            string result = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(zapros, 0));
            string secondr = result.Remove(0, zlen);
            string firstr = secondr.Split(finish)[0];
            return firstr;
        }

Comment: Понятно, `Substring`, вот это я от вас и ожидал с самого начала. Почему вы не используете предназначенные для этого парсеры? К примеру `HtmlAgilityPack` - весь ваш код тогда будет в 2-3 строки.

Comment: Изобретаю велосипед...

Comment: Вот этого я вам очень не советую делать, не работайте с HTML как с текстом, это к в корне не верно! На крайний случай - регулярки (и то бред). Посмотрите мое первое сообщение, там ссылка, по ней найдете несколько способов работы с HTML, выберите подходящий и попробуйте сделать через него. Например через HtmlAgilityPack решить вашу задачу можно одним запросом `var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@itemprop='name']");` (предварительно загрузив данные) это конечно если имя известно, если нет, то чуть по другому, но не суть, главное не работайте с HTML как с текстом!!

Comment: Благодарю! Вы меня очень выручили!

Comment: Давайте тогда закроем дубликатом.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net)