# Составить регулярное выражение для HTML текста с определенными тегами

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярные выражением выделить текст между тегами `color: #21201e">` и `<' + '/div>` помогите пожалуйста, мне нужно конкретно выделить этот текст конкретно между двумя этими тегами

Текст примерно такой:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
var borq='';
borq += '<' + 'article style="margin: 15px auto; max-width: 560px;"><' + 'div style="background:#fff; border: 1px solid #e6e5e0; border-radius: 3px"><' + 'header style="display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; -webkit-box-align: flex-startnpm; -ms-flex-align: flex-startnpm; align-items: flex-startnpm; -webkit-box-pack: justify; -ms-flex-pack: justify; justify-content: space-between; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 12px; color: #827e7c"><' + 'a style="margin: 0; padding: 15px 15px 12px; color: #859900; text-decoration: none" href="/quote/451014">#451014<' + '/a><' + 'span style="padding: 15px 15px 12px">28.06.2018<' + '/span><' + '/header><' + 'div style="margin: 0 1px; padding: 0 15px 18px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; color: #21201e">Вот есть люди (много людей), кто от армии упорно &quot;косит&quot;. А был у меня знакомый, который яро желал вступить в ряды оборонительных сил любимой страны. Настало время призыва, так он руку сломал, в футбол играя. Ладно, говорит, не беда - на следующий призыв пойду, буду уже здоровый, как бык, к тому времени. Окей, приходит время призыва, всё отлично, его берут в ВДВ. Рад страшно. Уже пора и очаливать в армию, так, ессесн, решили проводить. Проводить не на поезд (или куда там ещё), а именно устроить прощальное пати. Напились, время около полдесятого вечера. Несомненно, закупленного заранее алкоголя не хватило и этот товаристч решил сходить в магазин за добавкой. Двадцать минут нет, полчаса... Телефон не взял с собой. Пошли искать. Поиски были рекордно короткими - шёл по лестнице в подъезде, упал. Там лежать и остался ВДВ-шник наш. Ногу поломал, мениск повреждён. В общем, теперь навечно непригоден. Сходил в армию, ять. А ведь, так хотел. Судьба?<' + '/div><' + 'footer style="margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; font-size: 13px; text-align: center"><' + 'a href="http://bash.im/" target="_blank" title="bash.im откроется в новом окне" style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px 50px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; text-align: center; color: #fff; background-color: #859900; border: none; border-radius: 3px; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">Больше на bash.im!<' + '/a><' + '/footer><' + '/div><' + '/article>';
setTimeout(function() {
  script.outerHTML += borq;
}, 500);
```

Код примерно такой:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] raw = wc.DownloadData("https://bash.im/forweb/?u");
string webData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
Regex regex = new Regex("<;.*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string[] str = regex.Split(webData);
string[] items = {""};
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == "") str = (from x in str where !items.Contains(x) select x).ToArray();

}
Console.Write(str[rnd.Next(1,str.Length-1)]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Нет, мне вот надо конкретно меж этими тегами выделить текст

Comment: @АндрейNOP почему это дубликат, если там по ссылке не html?

Comment: @tym32167 в топике [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354) не html?

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет, в этом вопросе по ссылке [https://bash.im/forweb/?u](https://bash.im/forweb/?u) не HTML

Comment: @tym32167, ок, триггер сработал на ключевые слова HTML и Regex

Comment: @АндрейNOP ноу проблем )

Answer (score 0):

По идее как-то так:

```
Regex.Match(@"color: #21201e"">(.*?)<' \+ '\/div>").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: не работает, вообще ничего не находит

Comment: Вроде исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
var text = Regex.Match(s, @"(?s)color:\s*#21201e"">(.*?)<'\s+\+\s+'/div>")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

Пример [работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/s9ASAw/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?s)` - модификатор, позволяющий точке находить переводы строки
- `color:` - строка `color:`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `#21201e"">` - строка `#21201e">`
- `(.*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: любые 0 и более символов, как можно меньше
- `<'` - строка `<'`
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
- `\+` - знак `+`
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
- `'/div>` - строка `'/div>`.