# Ошибка при использовании String.Substring(int x, int y) ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, строки, substring

### Есть задача:

Найти определенную строку и вырезать оттуда 4-х значный идентификатор.

#### Попытка реализации:

```
string source = reader.ReadToEnd();
int findIndex = source.IndexOf("Логин_Пользователь"); // индекс = 408694
int y = source.Length; // посмотрел общую размерность source = 443406

var h = source[findIndex]; // тут я проверял что возможно получить значение строки по индексу (Получили 'Л')
var z = source[findIndex-62] // тут тоже есть значение '<'


source = source.Substring(findIndex - 62, findIndex); // вырезаем из общего html строку в которой будем искать идентификатор
// и именно тут выходит ошибка
// > System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Индекс и длина должны указывать на позицию в строке.



source = source.Substring(source.IndexOf("param1=")+7, 4); // исходя из полученой ранее строки, вырезаем 4 знака после param1=

Console.WriteLine(source); // должны получить идентификатор состоящий из 4 знаков
```

К сожалению, не могу понять почему в моей реализации возникает такая ошибка, ведь индекс и длина действительно указывают на позицию в строке (это было проверено в переменных var h и var z)

При этом, если в Substring использовать индексы меньшей длины например так:

`source = source.Substring(11186 - 62, 11186)`

Ошибки не произойдёт и значение будет получено.

Прошу подскажите чего я не замечаю/не понимаю.

Ранее меня отсылали на статью [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net) и закрыли статью.
Не совсем понял в чём была причина, поэтому убрал все тэги связанный с парсингом и html, поскольку считаю, что у меня вопрос именно по работе с методом Substring ( о чем я описал в заголовке ), а не конкретно с парсингом.

Comment: @tym32167 Посмотрите пожалуйста исправленный вопрос.

Comment: вопрос решен, проблема была в моей невнимательности 
`source = source.Substring(findIndex - 62, 62);` \\ после исправления стало работать корректно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос решен, проблема была в моей невнимательности
`source = source.Substring(findIndex - 62, 62);`
после исправления стало работать корректно