# C# как найти подстроку в строке

Tags: c#

Есть строка:

```
<link rel="us" type="application/" title="href="http://site.com/value/THISWORD/feed/" /><script type="text/javascript"><div id="menu-wrapper" class="menu-wrapper ">
```

Нужно получить отдельно слово "THISWORD", HTML текст постоянно разный, единственное что перед ним постоянно "/value/" и в конце "/".
Как это можно сделать?
Спасибо:)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/222542

Comment: @Bulson, href="http://site.com/value/THISWORD/feed/" постоянно в разных местах и разных тегах, просто  распарсить HTML не получается

Comment: в HTML  может быть несколько повторений "http://site.com/value/THISWORD/feed/, мне нужно найти первое вхождение которое начинается с   /value/ и заканчивается /

Comment: Такая ссылка может быть только одна на документ? Звучит как задача для регулярных выражений.

Comment: Если вы работаете с HTML и у вас есть инструментарий для работы с ним, то наверно стоит найти решение именно под него, к примеру через XPath будет что-то по типу такого: `//link[contains(@href, 'value/')]`, далее берем например HAP и пишем `.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//link[contains(@href, 'value/')]");`, все, у вас на руках первый найденный `link`, где `href` содержит `value/`. Если же у вас нету такого инструментария и вы его по какой-то причине не хотите ставить, то сморите в сторону регулярок, либо банальным `.IndexOf()` вырезайте нужное. P.S. Мне очень не нравиться ваш ник!

Comment: у меня вышло вот так https://regex101.com/r/dnleJE/1/